# vectorized array creation from a list of start/end indices

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a two-column matrix `M` that contains the start/end indices of a bunch of intervals:

```
startInd   EndInd
1          3
6          10
12         12
15         16
```

How can I generate a vector of all the interval indices:

```
v = [1 2 3 6 7 8 9 10 12 15 16];
```

I'm doing the above using loops, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant vectorized solution?

```
v = [];
for i=1:size(M,1)
    v = [v M(i,1):M(i,2)];
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution I like to use for this particular problem, using the function [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
v = zeros(1, max(endInd)+1);  % An array of zeroes
v(startInd) = 1;              % Place 1 at the starts of the intervals
v(endInd+1) = v(endInd+1)-1;  % Add -1 one index after the ends of the intervals
v = find(cumsum(v));          % Perform a cumulative sum and find the nonzero entries
```

Comment: Yes, I knew there is an easy solution. Very elegant. +1

Comment: Note that the OPs solution is actually faster if idxs can be large, e.g., idxs = [1 3; 6 11; 12 12; 25000 26000] on my machine.

Answer (score 6):

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@colon,M(:,1)',M(:,2)','UniformOutput',false))
```

I don't have IMFILL, but on my machine this method is faster than the other suggestions and I think would beat the IMFILL method due to the use of find.

It can be made even faster if M is set up transposed (and we adjust the third and fourth arguments of arrayfun).

Comment: For inputs such as idxs = [1 3; 6 11; 12 12; 25000 26000], this solution is faster than gnovice's, but the OP's simple for loop is much faster still. For the OP's example input, this is slower than gnovice's and slower than the OP's for loop too.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an even better solution I'm somehow not seeing, but here's a version using [IMFILL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imfill.html)

```
startInd = [1,6,12,15];
endInd = [3,10,12,16];

%# create a logical vector with starts and ends set to true to prepare for imfill
tf = false(endInd(end),1);
tf([startInd,endInd]) = true;

%# fill at startInd+1 wherever startInd is not equal endInd
tf = imfill(tf,startInd(startInd~=endInd)'+1); %' SO formatting

%# use find to get the indices
v = find(tf)'  %' SO formatting

v =
     1     2     3     6     7     8     9    10    12    15    16
```

Answer (score 0):

Very weird solution IMHO creating temporary strings and using EVAL. Can be also one-liner.

```
tmp = cellstr(strcat(num2str(M(:,1)),{':'},num2str(M(:,2)),{' '}));
v = eval(['[' cell2mat(tmp') ']']);
```

I know it will probably not work on large matrix. Just for fun.