# Finding islands of zeros in a sequence

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Imagine you have a very long sequence. What is the most efficient way of finding the intervals where the sequence is all zeros (or more precisely the sequence drops to near-zero values `abs(X)<eps`):

For simplicity, lets assume the following sequence:

```
sig = [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0];
```

I'm trying to get the following information:

```
startIndex   EndIndex    Duration
3            6           4
12           12          1
14           16          3
25           26          2
30           30          1
```

then using this information, we find the intervals with duration >= to some specified value (say `3`), and returning the indices of the values in all these intervals combined:

```
indices = [3 4 5 6 14 15 16];
```

That last part is related to a previous question:

> [MATLAB: vectorized array creation
>   from a list of start/end indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807270/matlab-vectorized-array-creation-from-a-list-of-start-end-indices)

This is what I have so far:

```
sig = [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0];
len = length(sig);
thresh = 3;

%# align the signal with itself successively shifted by one
%# v will thus contain 1 in the starting locations of the zero interval
v = true(1,len-thresh+1);
for i=1:thresh
    v = v & ( sig(i:len-thresh+i) == 0 );
end

%# extend the 1's till the end of the intervals
for i=1:thresh-1
    v(find(v)+1) = true;
end

%# get the final indices
v = find(v);
```

I'm looking to vectorize/optimize the code, but I'm open to other solutions.
I have to stress that space and time efficiencies are very important, since I'm processing a large number of long bio-signals.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

These are the steps I would take to solve your problem in a vectorized way, starting with a given vector `sig`:

- First, threshold the vector to get a vector `tsig` of zeros and ones (zeroes where the absolute value of the signal drops close enough to zero, ones elsewhere):

  ```
  tsig = (abs(sig) >= eps);  %# Using eps as the threshold
  ```
- Next, find the starting indices, ending indices, and duration of each string of zeroes using the functions [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) and [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html):

  ```
  dsig = diff([1 tsig 1]);
  startIndex = find(dsig < 0);
  endIndex = find(dsig > 0)-1;
  duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
  ```
- Then, find the strings of zeroes with a duration greater than or equal to some value (such as 3, from your example):

  ```
  stringIndex = (duration >= 3);
  startIndex = startIndex(stringIndex);
  endIndex = endIndex(stringIndex);
  ```
- Finally, use [the method from my answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807270/matlab-vectorized-array-creation-from-a-list-of-start-end-indices/2807994#2807994) to generate your final set of indices:

  ```
  indices = zeros(1,max(endIndex)+1);
  indices(startIndex) = 1;
  indices(endIndex+1) = indices(endIndex+1)-1;
  indices = find(cumsum(indices));
  ```

Comment: Was going to suggest this, more or less exactly.

Comment: @gnovice, thanks for your solution. How could I extend it to detect the values in-between pairs of numbers? `sig = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 0];`, I would like to obtain: `indices = [7 8 9 10];`, and also their start/end/duration. In the example the pair of numbers is`[1,-1]`, but they can also be `[-1,1]`,  `[-1,-1]`, or ` [1,1]`? In a sequence, we can have many of those pairs.

Answer (score 10):

You can solve this as a string search task, by finding strings of zeros of length `thresh` (STRFIND function is very fast)

```
startIndex = strfind(sig, zeros(1,thresh));
```

Note that longer substrings will get marked in multiple locations but will eventually be joined once we add in-between locations from intervals start at `startIndex` to end at `start+thresh-1`.

```
indices = unique( bsxfun(@plus, startIndex', 0:thresh-1) )';
```

Note that you can always swap this last step with the CUMSUM/FIND solution by @gnovice from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807270/matlab-vectorized-array-creation-from-a-list-of-start-end-indices/2807994#2807994).

Comment: thats definitely the shortest vectorized solution, I wonder how It compares to the other two methods: `diff/find` by @gnovice and `conv` by @emailhy

Answer (score 1):

```
function indice=sigvec(sig,thresh)
    %extend sig head and tail to avoid 0 head and 0 tail

    exsig=[1,sig,1];
    %convolution sig with extend sig
    cvexsig=conv(exsig,ones(1,thresh));
    tempsig=double(cvexsig==0);

    indice=find(conv(tempsig,ones(1,thresh)))-thresh;
```

Answer (score 1):

the above answer by genovice can be modified to find the indices of non-zero elements in a vector as:

```
    tsig = (abs(sig) >= eps);
    dsig = diff([0 tsig 0]);
    startIndex = find(dsig > 0);
    endIndex = find(dsig < 0)-1;
    duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most MATLAB/"vectorized" way of doing it is by computing a convolution of your signal with  a filter like [-1 1]. You should look at the documentation of the function conv. Then on the output of conv use find to get the relevant indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As gnovice showed, we'll do a threshold test to make "near zero" really zero:

```
logcl = abs(sig(:)) >= zero_tolerance;
```

Then find regions where the cumulative sum isn't increasing:

```
cs = cumsum(logcl);
islands = cs(1+thresh:end) == cs(1:end-thresh);
```

Remembering [gnovice's great method for filling in ranges of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2807994/103167)

> ```
> v = zeros(1,max(endInd)+1);   %# An array of zeroes
> v(startInd) = 1;              %# Place 1 at the starts of the intervals
> v(endInd+1) = v(endInd+1)-1;  %# Add -1 one index after the ends of the intervals
> indices = find(cumsum(v));  %# Perform a cumulative sum and find the nonzero entries
> ```

We note that our `islands` vector already has ones in the `startInd` locations, and for our purposes `endInd` always comes `thresh` spots later (longer runs have runs of ones in `islands`)

```
endcap = zeros(thresh,1);
indices = find(cumsum([islands ; endcap] - [endcap ; islands]))
```

## Test

```
sig = [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0];
logcl = abs(sig(:)) >= .1;
cs = cumsum(logcl);
islands = cs(1+thresh:end) == cs(1:end-thresh);
endcap = zeros(thresh,1);
indices = find(cumsum([islands ; endcap] - [endcap ; islands]))
```

> ```
> indices =
>
>      2
>      3
>      4
>      5
>     13
>     14
>     15
> ```