# Count the occurrence of consecutive 1s in 0-1 data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a set of 1s and 0s. How do I count the maximum number of consecutive 1s?

(For example, `x = [ 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ....]`). Here the answer is 3 because the maximum number of times 1 occurs consecutively is 3.

I was looking at some search and count inbuilt function, however I have not been successful.

Comment: Thanks ... I didn't know about the idea of acceptance :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
max( diff( [0 (find( ~ (x > 0) ) ) numel(x) + 1] ) - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution but it might be overkill:

```
L = bwlabel(x);
L(L==0) = [];
[~,n] = mode(L)
```

Sometimes it's better to write your own function with loops ; most of the time it's cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
x = randi([0 1], [1 100]);                %# random 0/1 vector

d = diff([0 x 0]);
maxOccurence = max( find(d<0)-find(d>0) )
```

which is inspired by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/matlab-finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence/3274416#3274416) to a somewhat similar question...

Answer (score 0):

Cody Problem 15 is find maximum consecutive ones in a 'binary' string.
This works quite nicely. As you can tell I'm quite pleased with it!
Cody size 19

```
max(cellfun(@numel,strsplit(x,'0')));
```