# Finding 5 consecutive successes using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a function which for 10 cycles finds the difference between individual sensor values and the average sensor value. The test will be done 100 times using this function. So every time cycle>10 I am forcing it to be zero so that in the 11th repetition it will restart counting from zero. Here is the code:

```
cycle=cycle +1;
if cycle>10
  cycle=0;
end

for i=1: TotalnoOfGrids
  for j=1: noOfNodes
    if abs(char(Allquants{i}(j))-char(mostCommonLetters {i}))>0
      if cycle>0
        wrong{i}(j)=wrong{i}(j)+1;
      else 
        wrong{i}(j)=0;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I need to know if the sensor performed 5 consecutive successes in the period of 10 cycles. How can I do that?

I thought of a loop but I read that it takes too much time.

Doing a search on the net I have found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330588/count-the-occurrence-of-consecutive-1s-in-0-1-data-in-matlab).

The problem is that the above function will be repeated for 100 cycles.I want for every 10 cycles see if there is consecutive successes so it is beeing done dynamically and I am not saving the success or failure status of the sensor for the cycles. So i do not have a vector containing 1 or 0 to use the function used in the above reference or as Jonas suggested

Comment: What counts as a success in your code?

Comment: i am counting the wrongs so if wrong is 0 success is 1 right?

Comment: You are counting wrongs for each grid, and each node. What are 5 successes in a row? Also, `wrong` is a cell array - is there a reason for that?

Comment: I have 9 grids and 20 sensor in each grid.the cell erray contains the number of times the sensors in the 9 grids gave wrong values.About the 5 successes I will take readings from all sensors if any sensor gave 5 consecutive times correct I need to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If a loop is the easiest thing, give it a try!** Just because you've read it "takes too much time" doesn't mean it really makes a difference for your case! It is true that in Matlab it often makes sense to avoid loops; but in your case, 100*20*9 (if I understand you correctly) loop iterations doesn't seem so bad yet (depending on your speed requirement).

**Edit (corrected answer)**

I now understand from your comments that the code you show us is surrounded by a `while` or `for` loop which is being run ~100 times, and that `Allquants` and `mostCommonLetters` probably change inside that loop. In this case my previous answer didn't work for you, since it counted successes on *different* sensors; this should be better now.

If I read your code correctly, the condition `abs(char(Allquants{i}(j))-char(mostCommonLetters {i}))>0` tells you that a result was "wrong"; consequently,

```
for i=1:TotalnoOfGrids
  this_cycle_successes(i,:)=char(Allquants{i})==char(mostCommonLetters{i});
end
consecutive_successes=(consecutive_successes+1).*this_cycle_successes;
```

would calculate how many successes you had in a row. Note you need to initialize `consecutive_successes` before starting your `cycle` loop, e.g.

```
consecutive_successes = zeros(9,20);
```

After the 10 cycles, you can check which sensors had 5 successes like this:

```
 has5successes = consecutive_successes>=5;
```

Note that this is a matrix operation, so now you will get 9*20 values, as you requested in your comment. This solution wouldn't require a loop over `j`.

Comment: the successes equation you wrote @Jonas will not count the number of successes in this way right? it will overwrite

Comment: Moreover i only get 9 values of has5successes where i suspect 9*20. will work on it to find a solution i hope

Comment: Your most recent comment contains *no* sentence of correct English; your last sentence is incomprehensible. Sorry, I'm giving up.

Comment: there is a dimention problem :?? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: if used this it is solved consecutive_successes=(consecutive_successes+1).*this_cycle_successes;