# Search for 3 or more consecutive ones in a binary vector and return their positions

Tags: matlab, row

I have a vector `A` of dimensions 24x1. The vector elements were randomly assigned 1,0 with the following code:

```
A=randi([0 1],n,1);.
```

I want to make a code so I can search the vector for three or more 1s in a row, and return the index of the row of ones.

Comment: Its not very clear. You you want to find 3 consecutive `1`s in an array. What does in mean "to print the cells"? What cells?

Comment: yes, please expand on what you want exactly. if the ones are consecutive you could use a `mask=ones(1,3)` and iterate comparatively row-wise

Comment: I want to search the array and when i find more than three 1 straight to print the array's blocks that got the ones.

Comment: For example if A[4] A[5] A[6] are 1 to print 4,5,6.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683988/count-numbers-of-consecutive-1s-and-0s-in-a-vector

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the indices of the *start* of each run of `m=3` ones:

```
m = 3;
ind_start = find(conv(A, ones(1,m), 'valid')==m);
```

So your desired result would be (add `0`, `1`, ...`m-1` to each index and remove duplicates):

```
ind = unique(reshape(bsxfun(@plus, ind_start, 0:m-1), 1, []));
```