# Matlab: find the length of longest substring in sequence

Tags: string, matlab, max, segment

**In matlab:**
I want to find the length of longest i-segment in  the sequence for i ∈{H,E }.

```
Example: HHHCCEEECCCHHHHCCCCC
lengh of longest H-segment in sequence is: 4
```

How should i do this?

Comment: Closely related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6330964/3293881. Thus, use this to find the max occurrences of `H` - `max( diff( [0 (find( ~ (string=='H' > 0) ) ) numel(string=='H') + 1] ) - 1)` and similarly for `E` and take the max of those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner with `regexp`:

```
max(cellfun(@numel, regexp(str, '([HE])\1+', 'match')))
```

Comment: This is a good shortcut, might have to retract the dup vote! +1

Comment: I agree it's almost a duplicate, but not quite. I didn't close it as dup because here the sequence has more than two values, and the search is for more than one of those values. Of course those differences are not very significant, but for beginners they might be