# Split an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, split

I have an array of integer numbers, and I want to split this array where 0 comes and a function that give me points of split.

Example: Array : 0 0 0 1 2 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 22 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 4 4 0

The function must return these numbers:

```
[ 3 10 ;14 20 ;22 25 ]
```

These numbers are index of start and end of nonzero numbers.

Comment: @amro - this is more like the inverse of that problem where OP is trying to find islands of non-zero values.

Comment: @Kev: to convert to the other, it's as simple as adding `array = (array==0);` at the start (or the other way around `array~=0`, depending on which way you are looking at it)...

Comment: @amro - true, but it's not an "exact" duplicate.

Comment: @Kev: I guess I should have called it `duplicate answers` rather than `duplicate question` :)

Comment: related question: [MATLAB: finding islands of zeros in a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/matlab-finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple vectorized solution using the functions [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) and [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html):

```
>> array = [0 0 0 1 2 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 22 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 4 4 0];  %# Sample array
>> edgeArray = diff([0; (array(:) ~= 0); 0]);
>> indices = [find(edgeArray > 0)-1 find(edgeArray < 0)]

indices =

     3    10
    14    20
    22    25
```

The above code works by first creating a column array with ones indicating non-zero elements, padding this array with zeroes (in case any of the non-zero spans extend to the array edges), and taking the element-wise differences. This gives a vector `edgeArray` with `1` indicating the start of a non-zero span and `-1` indicating the end of a non-zero span. Then the function [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) is used to get the indices of the starts and ends.

One side note/nitpick: these aren't the indices of the starts and ends of the non-zero spans like you say. They are technically the indices *just before* the starts and *just after* the ends of the non-zero spans. You *may* actually want the following instead:

```
>> indices = [find(edgeArray > 0) find(edgeArray < 0)-1]

indices =

     4     9
    15    19
    23    24
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
a = [0 0 0 1 2 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 22 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 4 4 0];

%#Places where value was zero and then became non-zero
logicalOn = a(1:end-1)==0 & a(2:end)~=0;

%#Places where value was non-zero and then became zero
logicalOff = a(1:end-1)~=0 & a(2:end)==0;

%#Build a matrix to store the results
M = zeros(sum(logicalOn),2);

%#Indices where value was zero and then became non-zero
[~,indOn] = find(logicalOn);

%#Indices where value was non-zero and then became zero
[~,indOff] = find(logicalOff);

%#We're looking for the zero AFTER the transition happened
indOff = indOff + 1;

%#Fill the matrix with results
M(:,1) = indOn(:);
M(:,2) = indOff(:);

%#Display result
disp(M);
```

Answer (score 2):

On the theme, but with a slight variation:

```
>>> a= [0 0 0 1 2 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 22 4 5 6 6 0 0 0 4 4 0];
>>> adjust= [0 1]';
>>> tmp= reshape(find([0 diff(a== 0)])', 2, [])
tmp =
    4   15   23
   10   20   25
>>> indices= (tmp- repmat(adjust, 1, size(tmp, 2)))'
indices =
    4    9
   15   19
   23   24
```

As `gnovice` already pointed out on the positional semantics related to `indices`, I'll just add that, with this solution, various schemes can be handled very straightforward manner, when calculating `indices`. Thus, for your request:

```
>>> adjust= [1 0]';
>>> tmp= reshape(find([0 diff(a== 0)])', 2, []);
>>> indices= (tmp- repmat(adjust, 1, size(tmp, 2)))'
indices =
    3   10
   14   20
   22   25
```