# Count group of ones in series

Tags: matlab

I have a series a=[100 200 1 1 1 243 300 1 1 1 1 1 400 1 900  600 900 1 1 1 ]
I have to count how many times 1 occur when it occurs in group.
First group of 1's, sum is 3 (lying between 200 and 243). 
Second group of ones lying between 300 and 400 is 5. Sum of all ones in each group is [3 5 1 3]. 
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: See [SplitVec](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24255-consecutive-vector-spliter/content/SplitVec.m) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6549883/1586200)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) on `a==1`. Bracket with `false` to assure the count is correct no matter what the starting or ending values of `a`. Finally, [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) the start and end of each run and subract:

```
d = diff([false, a==1, false]);
result = find(d==-1) - find(d==1);
```

In your example this gives

```
result =
     3     5     1     3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luis Mendo. It helped.