# Need to analyze a set of vectors with 0 and positive integers

Tags: java, matlab, numbers

I am using Matlab, and I have a 1x200 vector of numbers.

I need to assign a "score" to the set of numbers by following these rules:

1. If there are 2 or 3 or 4 consecutive positive numbers, then 0.5 points
2. If there are five or more consecutive positive numbers, then 1.0 points
3. If there isn't any consecutive positive number, for example: 0 0 0 6 0 0, then 0.0 point. (ignore it, consider that positive number as zero)
4. If there is only one zero in the middle of a run of positive integers, then ignore that zero (consider it as a positive integer)
5. If there are two or more consecutive zeroes, *that* breaks the run of consecutive positive numbers.

Example: 30 43 54 0 0 0 41 54 14 10 1 0 0 0 0 32 41 98 12 0 0 0  (2.0 points total)

At the end, there should be a tally of the points.

Are there any useful functions for this type of problem?

Comment: What have you done in attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: To "MATLAB regulars": I would appreciate if you joined the meta-discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108521/168373 about the influx of homework-style questions our community has recently seen.

Comment: @ starkey: The vector is part of a bigger vector. Graphing that is an image of  a super resolution image of a silicon chip. These numbers represent the intensity of the image at various pixels. Knowing the "points" will help me calculate the period  of the illumination lattice as the number of the CCD pixels. I tried to keep the problem simple ('points') for my wide-range of audience so it may sound homework to you. 

@strictlyrude27: series of for and if statements, array indexing. I will post solution after debugging.

Comment: Shouldn't your answer for your sample data be 2.0?  1 run of 3, one of 4, = 1.0, one run of 5 = 1.0, total 1.0?

Comment: a similar question: [MATLAB: finding islands of zeros in a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/matlab-finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on my understanding of the question, as noted in my question above.  I've "unsuppressed" all output, so you can see what's going on.

```
%Rules:
%1. If there are 2 or 3 or 4 consecutive positive numbers, then 0.5 point
%2. If there are five or more consecutive positive numbers, then 1.0 point
%3.  And if there isn't any consecutive positive number, for example: 
%   0 0 0 6 0 0, then 0.0 point. (ignore it, consider that positive 
%   number as zero)
%4. if there is only one zero in the middle of positive integers = ignore 
%   that zero (consider it as a positive integer)
%5. If there are two or more consecutive 0, THEN no point.

%testData = [0 30 43 54 0 0 0 41 54 14 10 1 0 0 0 0 32 41 98 12 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 ];
testData = [30 43 54 0 0 0 41 54 14 10 1 0 0 0 0 32 41 98 12 0 0 0 ];
posa = testData>0;
%add 0s at each end so that the diffs at the ends work.
diffa = diff([0 posa 0])
starts = find(diffa ==1)
ends = find(diffa==-1)

% Rule 4 if any end (-1) is immediately followed by a start, that means that there 
%   is a 0 in the middle of a run.  substitute a 1 in the position and recalc.
midZeroLengths = starts(2:end) - ends(1:(end-1));
%pad to account for the fact that we only compared part.
midZeroLengths = [midZeroLengths 0];
if any(midZeroLengths == 1);
    testData(ends(midZeroLengths==1)) = 1;
    posa = testData>0;
    %add 0s at each end so that the diffs at the ends work.
    diffa = diff([0 posa 0])
    starts = find(diffa ==1)
    ends = find(diffa==-1)  
end

runs = ends-starts
halfs = (runs > 1) & (runs < 5)
wholes = (runs > 4)
final = sum(halfs)*0.5 + sum(wholes)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
str = repmat('a', 1, numel(testData));
str(testData > 0) = 'b';
m = regexp(str, 'b+(ab+)*', 'match');
n = cellfun(@numel, m);
score = 0.5 * sum(n >= 2 & n <= 4) + 1.0 * sum(n >= 5);
```

Note that I haven't run this, so there may be errors.