# Finding the average number of consecutive same value elements in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a question that I couldn't solve by myself, and search results have also not been what I am looking for (unless I missed one that explains it all, in which case I apologize!)

I have a system that can be in three states, `S = S1, S2 and S3`. It can change between these three states with a certain probability: From `S1` to `S2` with `P1`, `S2` to `S1` with `P2`, `S2` to `S3` with `P3` and `S3` to `S2` with `P4`. However, to make things simple, I'll begin with `P1 = P2 = P3 = P4 = P`.

Now I have a dataset, an array of 1000000 values which correspond to these specific states. So `S1` means a `1` in the array, `S2` means `0.5` and `S3` means `0`.

So now I want to find out how long the average 'string' of consecutive 1's, or 0.5's, or 0's is in my array. As it is simply a binomial process, (change state with p = P), I should in principle be able to extract P from this information. Although I'm not sure how yet, as I can't simply fit the distribution of 'string lengths' to the binomial distribution, can I?

In any case, a good place to start would be to be able to extract the length of 'strings' of consecutive equal values. Could anyone point me in a direction for where to start?

Edit: 
I see that `fitdist` could fit the 'string lengths' to the binomial distribution. So now I simply want to find how to create an array that contains the 'string lengths' for consecutive 1's, 0.5's and 0's.

Edit 2: It seems that [Series of consecutive numbers (different lengths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850341/series-of-consecutive-numbers-different-lengths) might be doing exactly what I want. I'll have a quick look at it, and if so I'll delete the post. I apologize!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something as simple as using a derivative. This will identify when there is a change in the sequence. Anywhere the derivative returns something other than 0, this indicates a change. Find what index those changes happen, and then you can find the differences between these indices to get the lengths. Here is some example code

```
% all just setup
a = 0*ones(1,randi([1,10]));
b = 1*ones(1,randi([1,10]));
c = 0.5*ones(1,randi([1,10]));
vals = {a,b,c};
len = 1e6;
temp = cell(1,len);
for i = 1:len
    index = randi([1,3]);
    temp{i} = vals{index};
end
mat  = cell2mat(temp);
% code that actually does what you need
mat = [mat,nan];
seqLengths = diff([0,find(diff(mat) ~= 0)]);
```

Please note that the `nan` is added to the end of your vector so that you will get a vector of the same length at the end. `nan` is used because it is assumed that your vector will contain all valid numbers, if not, `nan` can be replaced with any value that does not match the last value in the matrix.

Comment: This makes sense, although it seems as if maybe it is a little more difficult than it has to be. But it definitely works! I'll see if I can come up with something quicker, but for now this at least gives me the length of the consecutive number strings.
Edit: See comments below, disregard this!

Comment: It is only two lines of code, and uses all built-in MATLAB optimized functions. Not sure you will find anything much faster in MATLAB, but go for it. If you do, please post it here. For a matrix of ~400000 elements, it only takes 0.2 seconds to run.

Comment: That was very ignorant of me. I responded way quicker than I should have, that is before understanding what the code did rather than seeing if it worked. You're right, super efficient!

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a binomial process, there is no need to count the average length. Count the transitions for each state:

```
y=sparse(x(1:end-1),x(2:end),ones(numel(x)-1,1))
```

And divide it by the total number of transitions:

```
z=y./sum(sum(y))
```

Comment: Hm alright, that makes sense. But what I really want to do is extract the probability of going from S1 to S2, from the length of the 'strings' of 1's, for example.

Comment: @user3183724: if you want to determine the number of sequences of the same state, then MZimmerman6's solution is the way to go. Strangely, you say that you actually want to estimate transition probabilities, as a comment on an answer that explains how to estimate transition probabilities!?

Comment: Strangely indeed. I guess I just didn't understand what Daniel R wrote, and I responded too hastily. I should take more time to understand what is going on. What Daniel suggested is using the maximum likelihood estimator for the geometric distribution, which is indeed the correct approach.