# How to count maximum number of recurring elements?

Tags: matlab, sequence

```
Grid_outage(:,1) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,2) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,3) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,4) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,5) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,6) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,7) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,8) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,9) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,10) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,11) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,12) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,13) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,14) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,15) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,16) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,17) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,18) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,19) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,20) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,21) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,22) = 0;
Grid_outage(:,23) = 1;
Grid_outage(:,24) = 0;
```

I would like to count the maximum number of Zeros that occur in a sequence, for e.g. I would like that above result be 8 which shows the maximum number of zeros that occur together, rather than the total number of zeros which is 16. 
How do I code that in matlab

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850341/series-of-consecutive-numbers-different-lengths and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of transparency a very simple algoritm.

Assume you can put your sequence in a vector X:

```
% Create X containing some zeros.
X = round(rand(30,1));

% Use a counter to count the number of sequential zeros.
count = 0;
% Use a variable to keep the maximum.
max_count = 0;

% Loop over every element
for ii=1:length(X);
    % If a zero is encountered increase the counter
    if(X(ii)==0)
        count=count+1;
    % If no zero is encountered check if the number of zeros in the last sequence was largest.
    elseif count>max_count
        max_count=count;
        count=0;
    % Else just reset the counter
    else
        count=0;
    end
end
% Check if the last number of the vector exceeded the largest sequence.
if(count>max_count)
   max_count=count;
end
```

EDIT: Dan's solution is more efficient starting from approximately ~200 elements.

[image: Dan is more efficient ok]

Comment: +1 for explicitly showing a simple algorithm, but this doesn't take advantage of using idiomatic Matlab and it's basic built-in functions. You can quite easily do this in a single line, and it will probably be more efficient too.

Comment: @Dan starting from ~200 elements your single line solution is indeed more efficient :) +1 for well-scaling solution

Answer (score 3):

```
max(diff(find(diff(Grid_outage))))
```

1. Find where a sequence of consecutive numbers changes using `diff`
2. Get the actual index numbers of where this happens using `find`
3. Use `diff` again to count the number of elements between each "transition"
4. Finally call `max` to get the largest sequence of consecutive numbers.

Note that you might have trouble if the largest sequence occurs at the edges, in this case I suggest that you first prepend and append an inverted bit to your matrix like this: `[1-Grid_outage(1), Grid_outage, 1-Grid_outage(end)];`

Comment: +1 Use `;` for the prefix/postfix

Comment: ya but maybe -1 because my solution would find the longest sequence of `1`s as well... I'll fix this now

Comment: If you only want the longest sequence of `0`s then rather use the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850341/series-of-consecutive-numbers-different-lengths

Comment: I do not agree with the answer in the link. It would be much better to replace the zero's in the line defining q by NaN's. So you can look for any number you want, also 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find how many times the parameter `x` occurs together in a sequence, you can use:

```
if a(:) == x
    result = length(a); % Whole vector has the x parameter
else
    result = max(find(a~=x,1,'first') - 1, length(a) - find(a~=x,1,'last')); % Maximum difference in the edge   
    if ~isempty(max(diff(find(a~=x))) - 1)
        if isempty(result)
            result = max(diff(find(a~=x))) - 1; % Maximum difference in the body
        elseif result < max(diff(find(a~=x))) - 1
            result = max(diff(find(a~=x))) - 1; % Maximum difference in the body
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 it works now. btw `find(a~=0)` can be replaced with just `find(a)`

Comment: @Dan you are right for that case, but with `find(a~=x)` you can define the variable `x` that has to be searched

Comment: It doesn't work where the longest sequence is on the edge. Also:

[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

returns an empty array.

Comment: @EJG89 check my edit. Now it works in the body, in the edge and when all the values are the same