# Can someone tell me what this function actually does?

Tags: matlab, vector

Hi i'm new to MATLAB and i was wondering what this function actually does.  The function was copied from a previous question that helped me out with a problem to find the frequency of a number in a row.

Link:
[Series of consecutive numbers (different lengths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850341/series-of-consecutive-numbers-different-lengths)

```
d=[3 2 4 2 2 2 3 5 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 9 2]
q = diff([0 d 0] == 2);
v = find(q == -1) - find(q == 1);
```

Comment: Gives the number of consecutive`2's` in the vector, `v= 1     3     1     5     1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets get to it step by step.

You have an array `d`:

```
d=[3 2 4 2 2 2 3 5 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 9 2]
```

and you apply to it

```
q = diff([0 d 0] == 2);
```

This takes the derivative of `[0 d 0] == 2`. Basically it takes the derivative of all the numbers that are 2. The result of `[0 d 0] == 2` is:

```
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

You can see that there are 1 whenever there was a 2 in the original vector, and it has a 0 in the begging and a 0 in the end. If we take the derivative of this by `q = diff([0 d 0] == 2)`:

```
q =

     0 1 -1 1 0 0  -1 0 0 0 1 -1 1 0 0 0 0 -1 1 -1
```

You get 1 whenever a 2 in the original vector appeared and a -1 when in disappeared. The last line finds just the 1 and just the -1 separately and substract the indices where they appeared, that way you can now how many numbers are between them. As 1 means "number 2 starts" and -1 means "no more number 2s in a row" this will give you the length of the series of 2s in a row.

```
v = find(q == -1) - find(q == 1);

v=
    1     3     1     5     1
```

There is a single 2 in the begining, then there is a series of 3 2s, then another single one, then 5 come and separated by a 9, the last one comes.

Comment: what does the find function accomplish? if i separate the 2 find functions to: i use
    v = find(q == -1)
    x = find(q == 1)
where
v = 3     7    12    18    20 
and
x = 2     4    11    13    19
where do these values come from?

Comment: Finds the indexes of the non zero items. You can Google thath ;)