# finding consecutive 0's in a vector and replacing it by 1's in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

I have a 1x1000 vector, consisting of 1's and 0's.
I would like to find four consecutive 0's in the vector and replace it by combination of 0's and 1's (for eg, 1101,1111,1010 any combination of the binary values from 1 to 15) but i should not replace or affect already existing 1's in the vector.

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurrences of four consecutive zeros? Do you want to replace all of them by the same binary number?

Comment: related question: [MATLAB: finding islands of zeros in a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/matlab-finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) (also look at its linked questions)

Answer (score 2):

Quick concept, scrolling window looking at each 4 element block and checks against an array of zeros.

```
%calling your vector "A" here
searchlen= 4 - 1; %remove 1 so when adding to index, takes correct # elements
zarray= zeros(1,searchlen+1);
for i=1:(length(A)-searchlen)
  if(isequal(A(i:i+searchlen),zarray))
    A(i:i+searchlen) = [1 0 0 1]; %replace with your code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying but when i compile this code i get an error "undefined function or method len for input argument of type double" one morething what will this code return? will it return me a modified vector?

Comment: should read length instead of len, I'll edit it into my code above. This code edits in place.

Comment: Thank you very much will try and get back to you!! and by the way what does the line searchlen=4 - 1 do? do i have to remove 1 in my code? or should i leave it as it is?

Comment: It comes from the way the number you compare are picked out. T=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7];T(2:2+4) gives [2 3 4 5 6], which you see it five elements long, you only want four

Comment: Vidar is correct in why I included the "-1" in the line. Besides that, if your array was actually called "A" then good news! You can copy and paste the above and it should work. You could also mix in some of the code above from Amro's solution if you had wanted random numbers replacing the 0's, or just go with his altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much AlwaysWrong, I have a small question what if i want to write your code in a function and that function should return me a modified matrix(0's replaced by 1's), how can i do that? and more over what if instead of 4 consecutive zeros, i have to find 30 consecutive zeros? how do i have to modify the code? please bare with me, i am very new to programming and matlab! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: add 'function b=fixzeros(A)' before the above, 'b=A' at the end (don't worry about it overwriting your original array in a function, the scope is different). The first number before the -1 in the searchlen line sets the number of consecutive 0s to look for(leave the -1 in after). The way it works right now, even if there are 30 consecutive 0s it only works on them 4 at a time but will get to them all eventually. If you change the number of zeros you're looking for, you would definitely need to change the replacement value I use in my example with something of the same length. A=fixzeros(A).

Comment: Thank u very much!! you are awesome. i have a small doubt!! what if i have, lets say two array A and B. Both are of same length and A array is my initial array and on this i ll perform a sweep operation whose result would be B(Some values of 1's would be missing)for example: value of array A is 111110011000 and B is 110000010000. as you can see 3rd, 4th,5th,9th term of A which was 1 has been changed to 0 in B. And now using the above function of yours, ill also change the value of 0's which is already present in A. But what if i want to change only the values of 1 which is changed into 0 in B

Comment: leaving the already existing zeros in A. Please if you could help me with this it will be a big favour to me!! And how can i write random values instead of 1001 in your code.. i am sorry i have commented in two parts as only 400 characters are allowed here in comment..

Comment: I don't have matlab in front of me at the moment. Again, you could look up the documentation for Amro's solution and use something like "dec2bin(randi([0 15]),4)" (4 here is the number of consecutive 0s if you change it, where the range [0 15] represents possible values,  [0 2^(length)-1] constrained). If I follow you correctly, you want to take the changed values in B and only keep the ones where A was not 1? Use logical masking. I think this works: B = B&B(A==1). Try debugging with output to make sure. Assumes size(B) == size(A)

Comment: A and B are the same matrix, i have a function that would perform a sweep operation and this sweep operation will add zeros in the place of 1 in A and will save it in B. Now This function of yours would take A as input and should add those 0's with random binary values and it should not add these random values in the places where it was already zero in A. for example 11100000111(A)=>sweep=>00000000111(B)=>your code=>10100000111 as you can see the 4th to 8th position of A should not change as they are also zero..is there any way i could perform this??

Comment: please help would be very much appreciated!! as i have an submission to do tomorrow!! Thank u very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you could use [STRFIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) to find the locations of all four-consecutive zeros

```
%# binary row-vector
x = [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0];

%# starting locations of four-consecutive zeros
idx = strfind(x, [0 0 0 0]);

%# random binary numbers (rows) used to replace the consecutive zeros
n = dec2bin(randi([1 15],[numel(idx) 1]),4) - '0';

%# linear indices corresponding to the consecutive-zeros
idx = bsxfun(@plus, idx', (0:3));

%'# replace the 4-zeros
xx = x;
xx(idx(:)) = n(:);
```

The result:

```
>> x
x =
     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
           \_______1st_______/

>> xx
xx =
     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
           \_______1st_______/

>> n
n =
     1     0     1     0      <-- 1st consecutive four-zeros replaced by this
     1     1     1     0      <-- 2nd
     1     0     1     1          etc...
```

Note that if the initial vector `x` contains consecutive-zeros of length longer than `4`, `strfind` will return multiple locations within that longer sequence. So further processing would be required depending to how you want to select `4` from the longer sequence (first occurring, last occurring, etc..)

Comment: Your final note is a non-issue if it is filling with random binary numbers. The second subset might replace 3 of the numbers just generated in the first subset, but the one that remained is still random.

Comment: @Kishorepandey - if  this answer helped you, hit the check mark next to it to officially accept it.