# find non-overlapping sequences of zeros in matlab arrays

Tags: matlab, vectorization

This is related to:
[Finding islands of zeros in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence).

However, the problem is not exactly the same:

Let's take the same vector with the above postfor the purpose of comparison:

```
sig = [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0];
```

What I am trying to find are the starting indices of islands of *n* consecutive zeros; however, overlapping is not allowed. For example for n=2, I want the result:
v=[3, 5, 14, 25];

I found the solution of [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3276934) brilliant as a starting point (especially with regards to strfind), but the second part of his answer does not give me the result that I expect. This is a non-vectorized solution that I have so far:

```
function v=findIslands(sig, n)
        % Finds indices of unique islands

        % sig       --> target vector
        % n         --> This is the length of the island

        % This will find the starting indices for all "islands" of ones
        % but it marks long strings multiple times
        startIndex = strfind(sig, zeros(1,n));

        L=length(startIndex);

        % ongoing gap counter
        spc=0;

        if L>0 % Check if empty
            v=startIndex(1);
            for i=2:L
                % Count the distance
                spc=spc+(startIndex(i)-startIndex(i-1));
                if spc>=n
                    v=[v,startIndex(i)];
                    % Reset odometer
                    spc=0;
                end
            end
        else
            v=[];
            display('No Islands Found!')
        end
```

I was wondering if someone has a faster vectorized solution to the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert everything into strings and use regular expressions:

```
regexp(sprintf('%d', sig(:)), sprintf('%d', zeros(n, 1)))
```

#### Example

```
>> sig = [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0];
>> n = 2;
>> regexp(sprintf('%d', sig(:)), sprintf('%d', zeros(n, 1)))

ans =
     3     5    14    25
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Whoever is interested in speed, should note that this vectorized solution becomes slower than the looped one that I have above when sig or n become large.

Comment: @CyDe Things can become a tad slow when it comes to very large strings. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

As an example let's look at the case where the run length you want is 2.

1. Convert vector to binary number
2. Set index = size-1, set starting = []
3. Loop until n < 4:
4. Is n divisible by 4?
5. Yes? Append index to starting. Set n = n / 4
6. No? Set n = n / 2
7. Goto 3

For any other run length replace 4 with 2**run.

Comment: Thank you, but I was actually looking for a vectorized solution as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use gnovice's answer from the same linked question. It's vectorized, and the runs where `duration == n` are the ones you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3274416/105904

Take the runs with `duration >= n`, and then divide `duration` by `n`, and that'll tell you how many consecutive runs you have at each position and how to expand the index list. This could end up faster than the regexp version, if your island density isn't too high.

Comment: As far as I see this will give you only the indices of the segments that are exactly equal to n. Not what I was looking for.