# Matlab: How to find ranges of ones?

Tags: matlab

I have a binary vector of 1s and 0s. I would like to find with a function ranges/islands of numbers 1.
For example: x = 0001111001111111000110 ...
I would need an answer like that: 4-7 (or 4 5 6 7), 10-16, 20-21 ...
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Hint: `R=1:length(x); R(x(2:end) != x(1:end-1))` gives the positions of transitions from 0 to 1 _or_ from 1 to 0. You just have to prune that array adding a zero to both ends of the original array `x = [0 x_original 0];`. In this case the first transition is guaranteed to be from 0 to 1 and the last from 1 to 0.

Comment: Another way would be to use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indices of the ones, than just look at the differences between successive indices.

Comment: Already answered on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant of Aki's solution (not tested a lot):

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0];
dx = diff([0, x, 0]);
start_pos = find(dx == 1);
end_pos = find(dx == -1) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a zero to both ends of the original array guarantees an even number of transitions (starting with from 0 to 1, and ending with from 1 to 0.) Then it's basically a matter of `diff` and finetuning the output.

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0];
% how to make that out from a string  xx="0001111001111111000110" is left
% as an exercise
y = [0 x 0];        %  make sure x="11"; has proper amount of transitions
R = 1:length(y)-1;  %  make an array of indices [1 2 3 4 5 ... end-1]
F = R(y(2:end) != y(1:end-1));          % finds the positions [4,8,10,17,20,22]
start_pos = F(1:2:end-1);  % gets 4,10,20
end_pos = F(2:2:end)-1;    % gets 7,16,21 adjusted
```

*Disclaimer*: untested.

Comment: Looks close to how I would do it, but why do you use the trick with `R` and not the built-in `find` function?

Comment: @BasSwinckels: Haven't upgraded my matlab skills much after 1991.