# Find the first longest consecutive set of 1's in a Vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, count

I have the following vector in matlab:

```
[1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
```

I want to be able to find the longest consecutive set of 1's (so in this case it would be 3) and then print the index where this set arises (`3` and `5`).

In this scenario `1 1 1` shows up twice, I would like it to make sure it prints the index of where the first set is.

What coding can I use for this - but without using any in-built matlab functions, only for loops.

Comment: is `if else` not allowed as well? have you tried anything?

Comment: Related: [analyzing sequences matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9192507/5358968), [Matlab: How to find ranges of ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18909268/5358968)

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes I can use if else statements, I've tried many loops but can't seem to get it to work correctly

Comment: share your code. We can't debug your code without seeing it. See [MCVE]

Comment: Another: [find longest continuous array with values exceeding a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32439805/5358968)

Comment: Yes there will only be zeros and ones

Comment: are you sure that it arises at `5` and not `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without built-in functions. I understand that you want the indices of the begin and end of the first longest sequence.

```
data=[1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1];

x=[data 0];

c=0;
for k=1:length(x)
  if x(k)==1
    c=c+1;
  else
    ind(k)=c;
    c=0;
  end
end

a=ind(1);
for k=2:length(ind)
   if ind(k)>a
       a=ind(k);
       b=k;
   end
end

Ones_start_ind=b-a
Ones_end_ind=b-1

% results:
Ones_start_ind =
 3
Ones_end_ind =
 5
```

Comment: `max` is a build-in function

Answer (score 2):

Here an implementation without matlab functions:

```
%Example Vector
V=[1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1  0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0] ;

%calculate the diff of input
diff_V=V(2:end)-V(1:end-1);
N=length(diff_V);

% prepare start and end variables
start_idx=[]; end_idx=[];
%loop to find start and end
for kk=1:N

    if diff_V(kk)==1 %starts with plus
        start_idx=[start_idx kk+1];
    end

    if diff_V(kk)==-1 %ends with minus
        end_idx=[end_idx kk];
    end

end
% check if vector starts with one and adapt start_idx
if start_idx(1)>end_idx(1)
start_idx=[1 start_idx];
end

% check if vector ends with one and adapt end_idx
if start_idx(end)>end_idx(end)
end_idx=[end_idx length(V)];
end

%alloc output
max_length=0;
max_start_idx=0;
max_end_idx=0;
%search for start and length of longest epoch
for epoch=1:length(start_idx)
    epoch_length=end_idx(epoch)-start_idx(epoch)+1;
    if epoch_length> max_length
        max_length=epoch_length;
        max_start_idx=start_idx(epoch);
        max_end_idx=end_idx(epoch);
    end
end
```

Output

```
max_length =

 3


max_start_idx =

 3

max_end_idx =

 5
```