# Finding index in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, for-loop

A = [011100111100]

Hi, I want to find the index of start and end 1 and make that into a sub array. I am parsing a file so I have to do this programmatically. I am programming in Matlab.

```
A = [011100111100]
      ^ ^ B = [1 1 1]
      2 4 B_index = [2 4] 
A = [011100111100]
           ^  ^ C = [1 1 1 1]
           7  10C_index = [7 10]
```

My try

```matlab
for i=1:length(A)
   % Added to stop the loop froming looping more than i.
   if i == A(end)
       break; % stops loop
   end;
   if A(i) == 1 && A(i+1) == 0
       start_index = i;
   end;
end;
```

This works to find the start index but I want to find the end as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding islands of zeros in a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence)

Comment: Is A a double array or a scalar?

Comment: wha is this tagged C ?

Comment: @Luis Mendo Wow that is a lot like my situation, i look through it.

Comment: @Arsalan Actually it's simpler here. I think it deserves a separate answer. I've removed my duplicate vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [ 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ]; %// example data
ind = diff([0 A 0]); %// detect changes
start_index = find(ind==1); %// a start is a positive change
end_index = find(ind==-1)-1; %// an end is (just before) a negative change
```

Comment: i will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Arsalan It tells you the positions where `ind` equals `1`,  that is, where a change from value `0` to `1`has ocurred. That corresponds to the beginning of each run of `1` values.