# how to find the "cutoff" index in a vector?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that contains "chuncks" of data , seperated by "chuncks" of almost-zero ( < epsilon)
for example:

```
[ 18, 19, 34, 27, 0.1, 0.02, 0.04, 0.15 , 19, 23, 20, 34 ]
```

lI would like to find the indexes where the almosא-zeros sequence begin and ends,
i.e: the index of 0.1 (5) and the index of 0.15 (8)

an important obsevastion is that there could be some almost-zeroes before the "cutoff" , but not a "long" sequence

for examle, if i have the vector:

```
[30 , 14, 15 , 89, 0.3, 17 , 40, 0.4, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 80, 16, 40, 1, 22]
```

i would like to get back the indexes: 8, 11

any suggestion for a goos loop-avoiding way to do that?

thank you

Comment: `diff(M < 0.1)` - ones are begins of zero-areas, minus ones are ends. You can use `find` if you want indices of those. This will probably need special handling for border conditions though.

Comment: yes but what I am looking for is a way to recognize a "long sequens" of zeros (and not for example a single one) and get is index, so after
diff(M < 0.1)
I'm still not getting what I need...

Comment: Indices of begins: `find(diff(A > 3) == 1)`, indices of ends: `find(diff(A > 3) == -1)`. This will still need some refining though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab, this kind of simple problems can be vectorized without any loops like so:

```
x = [30 , 14, 15 , 89, 0.3, 17 , 40, 0.4, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 80, 16, 40, 1, 22];
epsilon = 0.5;
close_to_zero = x < epsilon;  % logical vector

% get logical vectors indicating 0-1 and 1-0 transitions
start = ~close_to_zero(1:end-1) & close_to_zero(2:end);
stop = close_to_zero(1:end-1) & ~close_to_zero(2:end);

% get indices of transitions
istart = find(start) + 1;
istop = find(stop);

% get length of sequences and kick out short ones
sequence_length = istop - istart + 1;
long_sequence = sequence_length > 2;  % logical vector
istart = istart(long_sequence)
istop = istop(long_sequence)
```

Result:

```
istart = 8
istop = 11
```

Note that this only works when the vector `x` does not start or end with a sequence close to zero. To solve this problem, you should pad `close_to_zero` with a False on the beginning and the end (`close_to_zero = [false, x < epsilon, false];`) and adjust the indices accordingly by subtracting 1.

Comment: Ever heard of `diff`? And your code will break if his data begins or ends with almost-null sequence.

Comment: Of course I know about `diff`, and using that might even be slightly faster. To explain these kind of tricks to beginners, however, I find it clearer to use the explicit boolean operations, which do exactly the same as diff. I was still updating my answer to handle the edge cases, should work now.