# summing portions of a vector using while loop

Tags: matlab, vector, while-loop

I am not very experienced with matlab and am struggling with while loops. I am trying to use a while loop to sum portions of a vector between zeros, and create a new vector of those sums.  Here is an example:

```
n=[1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3]
```

I want an out put vector

```
m=[4,8,7]
```

I have tried to even find a loop that will sum just the first section for starters but all of the while loops I have tried just run infinitely.

e.g.

```
n = [1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];

while n > 0

    m=sum(A)

end
```

Comment: With the way you've defined `n`, your predicate `n > 1` is never going to evaluate to logical `0` (i.e. MATLAB's false), and you're indeed gonna get caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are there two zeros consecutively, in any case? Also, just keep in mind that you should not use `while` loop for this kind of problem in MATLAB. You can use better approaches.

Comment: There are some cases with consecutive zeros and I am open to learning how to do this without a while loop if that would indeed be better.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3274416/1586200) answer and apply it your case.

Comment: @user4212064 You should accept the answer which suited you the most by clicking the check-mark on the left hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cumsum` function is really good for this sort of thing.  It will add across zeros, so you grab the value at each of the zeros (before or after doesn't matter, since the zero doesn't affect the sum), and then find how much the sum changed between zeros -- that's the sum of the numbers between.  And we'll make sure to subtract nothing from the sum at the first zero.

```
sums = cumsum(n(:));
sums = [0; sums(n == 0); sums(end)];
m = diff(sums)
```

This will give you a column vector, use the transpose (`'`) on the last line if you want a row vector.

One could instead force zeros at the beginning and end like quickbug does:

```
sums = cumsum([0; n(:); 0]);
m = diff(sums(n == 0))
```

If there are consecutive zeros, my answer treats those as having a zero-length sublist, so the sum of that sublist (zero) will be present in the result at the appropriate spot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you NEED to look at the examples in the mathworks while loop [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) for a better understanding.

Your problem is that the statement (n > 0) is always true. If you add another variable `index`, you can get something to work like

```
n = [1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];
index = 1;
m = 0;
while n(index) ~= 0
    m = m + n(index);
    index = index + 1;
end
```

That will get you `m = 4;` You will have to add another loop to generate the entire vector (using this approach). You can add a second loop with another index that runs until `index > length(n)`.

But, if you haven't already, go read the mathworks documentation on while loops, for loops, and anything else that you think is relevant.

**EDIT: Better Solution**

I used `find` and `length` and also concatenated some values together.

```
n = [1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];   
idx = find(n ==0); %find where n = 0;
idx = [0 idx length(n)+1]; %add start and endpoints of the vector
for i = 1:length(idx)-1 %loop through each space that contains numbers
    m(i) = sum(n(idx(i)+1:idx(i+1)-1)); %sum up the values in between the indices 
end
```

If there are any consecutive zeros, they will generate a value of m equal to 0; You can remove this using

`m(m==0) = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Since `while` is so important for you, use this:

```
n=[1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];
m = 0;
n(end + 1 ) = 0;    % add a zero for detection
i = 1;
k = 1;
while i <= length(n)    
      while n(i) > 0
            m(k) = m(k) + n(i);
            i = i + 1;
      end
      m(end + 1) = 0;  % add a new column
      i = i + 1;
      k = k + 1;
end
m(end) = [];
```

gives, `m = [4 8 7];`

Answer (score 0):

```
n=[1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3] ;
n = [0, n, 0] ;
ix = find(n==0) ;
m = zeros(1,length(ix)-1) ;
for k=2:length(ix)
    m(k-1) = sum(n(ix(k-1):ix(k))) ;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` to iterate over `n` and update `m` based on the values you touch

```
n = [1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];
m = 0;
idx = 1;
while idx <= numel(n)
    if n(idx) > 0
        m(end) = m(end) + n(idx);
    else
        m(end+1) = 0;
    end
    idx = idx + 1;
end
```

If `n(idx)` is positive (I'm taking from the code snippet that you are interested in positive values, if you are interested in non-zero values just change it to `n(idx)~=0`), add it to the last element in `m` otherwise add a new element to `m` to accommodate next run. This is in principle a `for` loop so you can rewrite it as

```
n = [1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];
m = 0;
for idx = 1:numel(n)
    if n(idx) > 0
        m(end) = m(end) + n(idx);
    else
        m(end+1) = 0;
    end
end
```

But now since you are dealing with a row vector you can use the power of `for` to iterate over elements of `n`:

```
n = [1,3,0,5,1,2,0,4,3];
m = 0;
for ni = n
    if ni > 0
        m(end) = m(end) + ni;
    else
        m(end+1) = 0;
    end
end
```

We probably should stop here but there is some interesting (but definitely less readable) way to get rid of the `if` clause:

```
m = 0;
for ni = n
    I = ni > 0; 
    m(end+~I) = I*(m(end) + ni);
end
```