# How to find the longest interval of 1's in a list [matlab]

Tags: arrays, matlab, list, matrix, intervals

I need to find the longest interval of 1's in a matrix, and the position of the first "1" in that interval.

```
For example if i have a matrix: [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

I need to have both the length of 7 and that the first 1's position is 11.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) as a basis, you can do as follows:

```
a = [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]


dsig = diff([0 a 0]);
startIndex = find(dsig > 0);
endIndex = find(dsig < 0) - 1;
duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
duration

startIdx = startIndex(duration == max(duration))
endIdx = endIndex(duration == max(duration))
```

This outputs:

```
duration =

     1     3     7


startIdx =

    11


endIdx =

    17
```

Please note, this probably needs double checking if it works for other cases than your example. Nevertheless, I think this is the way in the right directions. If not, in the linked anwser you can find more info and possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple intervals of one of the same length, it will only give the position of the first interval.

```
A=round(rand(1,20)) %// test vector
[~,p2]=find(diff([0 A])==1); %// finds where a string of 1's starts
[~,p3]=find(diff([A 0])==-1); %// finds where a string of 1's ends
le=p3-p2+1; %// length of each interval of 1's
ML=max(le); %// length of longest interval
ML %// display ML
p2(le==ML) %// find where strings of maximum length begin (per Marcin's answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of a brute force approach;

```
clc; clear all; close all;
A=  [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ];
index = 1;
globalCount = 0;
count = 0;
flag = 0; %// A flag to keep if the previous encounter was 0 or 1 
for i = 1 : length(A)
    if A(i) == 1
        count = count + 1;
        if flag == 0 
            index = i
            flag = 1;
        end

    end
    if A(i) == 0 || i == length(A)
        if count > globalCount
            globalCount = count;
        end
        flag = 0;
        count = 0;
    end

end
```