# Count occurrences of ones in islands across rows - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I need help with the following functions: histc and numel in either a for loop or vectorized code. I have a matrix which could be of any dimension. The code needs to output the number of occurrences an element occurs in an interval until the the end of each row. So for the following example, I want to find how many occurrences the number 1 occurs in row 1. So in row 1, the number one occurs two times before being interrupted by two 0's. Then it occurs once more in the last column. So the output would be 2 1.

I appreciate any help. Thank you

```
x = hist( data, numel(unique(data)) );
y = histc( data, unique(data) );

data (input) 5x5

1   1   0   0   1
1   1       1   1
0           0   1
0   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1

y (output) 

2 1
2 2
1
3
1 3
```

Comment: What do the blank entries symbolize? 0 as well?

Comment: Also, check out this post for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence - This only finds islands of zeros, but you can modify it so that you apply it on the **reverse** of the problem (0s become 1s and 1s become 0s), and do this for every row of your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x` to be the input array, this could be one approach -

```
[nrows,ncols] = size(x);
new_ncols = ncols + 2;

%// Pad one column of zeros on left and right sides of x
x_pz = [zeros(nrows,1) x zeros(nrows,1)] 

%// Flatten padded x
x_pzf = reshape(x_pz',[],1)'

%// Start & end indices of islands of ones for flattened padded x
starts = strfind(x_pzf,[1 0]);
ends = strfind(x_pzf,[0 1])

row_ids = ceil(starts/new_ncols); %// row IDs for  each island of ones

%// Start & end indices of islands of ones for flattened non-padded (corrected) x
starts_cor = ends - 2*(row_ids-1)
ends_cor = starts - (2*row_ids-1)

%// Get number of elements in each island of ones 
counts = ends_cor - starts_cor + 1

%// Bin row_ids for each row of input array
counts_per_row = histc(row_ids,1:nrows)

%// Now setup output array with conts for each island corresponding to each
%// row ending up in its each row and setting the blank spaces as NaNs
mask = bsxfun(@ge,counts_per_row,(1:max(counts_per_row))') %//'
y = NaN(size(mask))
y(mask) = counts
y = y'
```

Code run -

```
>> x (modified from the original one to test out more varied situations)
x =
     1     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0
     1     0     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0     1
>> y
y =
     2     2   NaN
     2     2   NaN
     1   NaN   NaN
     3   NaN   NaN
     1     4   NaN
     6   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     1     1
```

If you are looking for a more intuitive and concise way to obtain and display the final output, you can use cell array for that. So, you can do something like this -

```
>> ycell = arrayfun(@(n) counts(row_ids==n),1:nrows,'Uni',0);
>> celldisp(ycell)
ycell{1} =
     2     2
ycell{2} =
     2     2
ycell{3} =
     1
ycell{4} =
     3
ycell{5} =
     1     4
ycell{6} =
     6
ycell{7} =
     []
ycell{8} =
     1     1     1
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. BTW the blank cells were simply cells with no elements. I very much appreciate the code explanations.

Comment: @Buntalan So, is `x` (input) a cell array?

Comment: No, it was not a cell array. I just didn't want to add confusion. The data will be exported back to Excel. Cell output isn't necessary. But thanks again.