# find specific zeros grouped in an array - matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, zero

I have an array like this one

```
a=[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];
```

and would like if the community would know an elegant way to find the last occurrence of `0` in the first group and the first occurrence of `0` in the last group of zeros. Please note there is always ones between the two groups of zeros. The answer should look like this

```
b=[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0];
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't understand how you're representing the answer. You should try to write the code yourself, then post here if you run into any issues.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) very helpful. Also everything related to *runlength encoding*.

Comment: Just curious - Did any of the approaches listed here work for you? If it did, consider accepting it?

Answer (score 3):

**[`strfind`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html)** based approach that works pretty well with numeric arrays to find *patterns* like these, seems like a good fit to solve it. Here's the implementation -

```
%// Find indices where we have matches of [0 1] and [1 0] corresponding to
%// the two cases as listed in the question
case1_idx = strfind(a,[0 1])
case2_idx = strfind(a,[1 0])

%// Initialize output array; set those required positions in it as ones
b = zeros(size(a))
b([case1_idx(1) case2_idx(end)+1]) = 1
```

Sample run -

```
a =
     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
b =
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this descriptive solution:

```
afterA = [a(2:end),nan]
beforeA = [nan,a(1:end-1)]

b = (a==0 & afterA==1) | (a==0 & beforeA==1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = diff(a)
res = zeros(size(a))
res(find(d==1)) = 1
res(find(d==-1)+1) = 1
```

or (assuming that `a` always starts and ends with a `0`), you would not even need to search the entire array

```
res = zeros(size(a))
res(find(a, 1, 'first')-1) = 1
res(find(a, 1, 'last')+1) = 1
```

Comment: I prefer this to the `conv` solution, as they are basically identical in functionality, but I find this easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

With convolution:

```
b = zeros(size(a)); %// initiallize
x = conv(2*a-1,[1 -1],'same'); %// convolution
b(find(x==2)) = 1; %// last zero in a run
b(find(x==-2)+1) = 1; %// first zero in a run
```

Or you could use the same approach with `diff` instead of `conv`:

```
b = zeros(size(a)); %// initiallize
c = diff(a); %// compute differences
b(find(c==1)) = 1; %// last zero in a run
b(find(c==-1)+1) = 1; %// first zero in a run
```

Comment: Why the `2*a-1` instead of `a`?

Comment: I make the sequence "bipolar" so that convolution with [1 -1] gives 2 if and only if there is 1 -1 in the sequence (originally 1 0), and -2 if -1 1 (originally 0 1)

Comment: Ok, I guess you might have some signal processing theory in mind, which I don't know about. It would work with `a` and `c==1`/`c==-1` though.