# Finding lengths of 0's separating islands of 1's and assigning them

Tags: matlab, count, zero

I have a vector with alternating 0's and 1's and would like to convert each "1" to the length of the zeros that precede it. For example, I have x and would like to get to y:

```
x = [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]

y = [0 0 2 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 2]
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: Is this different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence ?

Answer (score 9):

One approach with [`find`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) & [`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) -

```
%// Initialize array, y with zeros and of length same as input, x
y = zeros(size(x))

%// Find places/indices where new values would be put
idx = find(x)   

%// Calculate new values which would be the differentiated values of indices 
%// and subtracted by 1 to account for the number of zeros in between two
%// non-zero values. We need to concatenate the indices array with one zero 
%// at the start to account for the starting non-zero value in x
y(idx) = diff([0 idx])-1
```

Comment: Very nice! It's hard to make it any simpler