# Create a text file using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make some changes in a list of precipitation data.
The data are in a `*.txt` file in this format:

```
50810,200301010600,0.0
50810,200301010601,0.0
50810,200301010800,0.0
50810,200301010938,0.1
50810,200301010947,0.1
50810,200301010957,0.1
```

Each file I have contains precipitation data per minute from 1 year.
The first number is just the station number, and this is equal for each line in the file.
In my original file, I have one line with data for every minute.

I want to make a new file that contains:

- Only lines with precipitation that is not zero, so I want to remove
  all the lines where the last number is zero. I've figured this out.
- If there is one whole hour with no precipitation, I want to remove all
  of the zero-lines and create a new line which says:
  50810,200301010600,0.0.  If there was no precipitation between 6 and 7
  am. at the 01.01.

  ```
  clear all

  data = load('jan-31des_2003.txt'); %opens file with data
  fid=fopen('50810_2003','w'); %opens empty file to write
  [nrow, ncol] = size(data); %size of data
  fprintf(fid,'%5s %12s %5s \r\n','Snr','Dato - Tid','RR_01') %Header

  for row = 1:nrow 

      y = data(row,2); %year
      m = data(row,3); % month
      d = data(row,4); % date
      h = data(row,5); % hour
      M = data(row,6); % minute
      p = data(row,8); % precipitation

      if p > 0
       fprintf(fid,'50810,%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d,%.1f \r\n',[y,m,d,h,M,p]);
      end
      if p==0 
          HERE I NEED SOME HELP
      end

  end

  fclose(fid);
  ```

What is the code for my desired formatting within the `if p==0` condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding islands of zeros in a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already imported your data as an M*3 array named infile and M is divisible by 60 and your data begins at the first minute of an hour, and you have an array outfile that will be written to a new file:

```
outfile = []
while ~isempty(infile)
    block = infile(1:60,:);          % Take one hour's worth of data
    if sum (block(:,3)==0) == 60     % Check if the last column are all zero
        outfile = cat(1, outfile, [block(1,1:2), 0]);  % If so, put one line to new array
    else
        filter = block(:,3)~=0;      % Otherwise, pick out only rows that the last column is not zeros
        outfile = cat(1, outfile, block(filter,:));    % Put these rows into the new array
    end
    infile(1:60,:) = [];             % Remove already processed data from original array
end
```

Then write the entire `outfile` array to file.

Comment: That Works. Thank you!

Comment: Please click on the v sign on the left and  accept the answer so that people will be happy to keep helping you with your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I also need help With another case. In some of my data only times having precipitation larger than zero are included in the original dataset.

So the Method above by checking all values hour by hour will not work.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should start another question? It sounds the problem needs a different solution.