# How to count number of consecutive ones in vector from the last position in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to count number of consecutive ones in a vector from last position in vector.

For example in `a=[0 1 0 1 0 1]` number of consecutive ones is 1.

In `b = [1 0 0 1 1 1]` number of consecutive ones is 3.

Comment: Can `a` only contain `1`s and `0`s?

Comment: I need only number of consecutive from the last position in a vector. Example c = [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1]. This number is 4

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. Can your vectors contain numbers other than `1` or `0`? e.g. is this a valid vector for your operation: `d = [0 1 1 0 2 1 1]`?

Comment: You could also potentially utilize the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) but for `1` rather than `0`

Comment: Try  FileExchange's  `seqle` . (Full disclosure: I'm the author)

Answer (score 2):

For a case, when you might have trailing zeros in the input -

```
find(A,1,'last') - find(diff(A)==1,1,'last')
```

Sample run -

```
>> A = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
A =
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
>> find(A,1,'last') - find(diff(A)==1,1,'last')
ans =
     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sum(a(find(diff(a),1,'last')+1:end))
```

or if you want to disregard the trailing `0`s then

```
sum(a(find(diff(a)==1,1,'last')+1:end))
```

And if you want this to work when `a` contains only `1`s then I would suggest

```
sum(a(find(diff([0,a])==1,1,'last'):end))
```

Comment: No problem, if this works then you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Could you (a) be more specific about what is not working about it and (b) answer the question I have already asked twice to clarify your question!

Comment: a =     [1     0     1     1     1     0] ; when I try your  code, I get 0 answer and I think answer is 3 in this example

Comment: The way you phrased your question, the correct answer is `0`. If you want to disregard trailing `0`s then just add an `==1` into the find. See my edit