# Return Maximum Amount of Sequential Numbers in a Row that Meet a Condition (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, sequence, counter

I have a large matrix of random values (e.g. 200,000 x 6,000) between 0-1 named 'allGSR.'
I used the following code to create a logical array (?) where 1 represents numbers less than .05

```
sig = (allGSR < .05);
```

What I'd like to do is to return an array of size 1 x 200,000 called maxSIG where each row represents the MAXIMUM number of sequential ones. So for example, if in row 1, columns 3-6 are ones, that is 4 ones in a row and if columns 100-109 are ones that is 10 ones in a row and if that is the maximum number of ones in a row I would like the first column of maxSIG to be the value '10.'

I have been doing this with for loops, if statements, and counters; this is ugly and tedious and was wondering if there is an easier or more efficient way.

Thank you for any insight.

EDIT: Whoops, should probably share the loop.
EDIT 2: So I just wrote out what my basic code is with a smaller (100 x 6,000) matrix. This code should run. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```
GSR = 6000;
samples = 100;
allGSR = zeros(samples, GSR);
for x = 1:samples
    y = rand(GSR, 1)';  %Transpose so it's 1x6000 and not 6000x1
    allGSR(x,:) = y;
end

countSIG = zeros(samples,1);
abovethreshold = (allGSR < .05); %.05 can be replaced by whatever
for z = 1:samples
    count = 0;
    holdArray = zeros(1,GSR);
    for a = 1:GSR
        if abovethreshold(z,a) == true
            count = count + 1;
        else
            count = 0;
        end
        holdArray(1,a) = count;
    end
    maxrun = max(holdArray);
    countSIG(z,1) = maxrun;
end
```

Comment: Share your loopy code?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about the omission. Added.

Comment: Could you list a smaller representative version of the actual `allGSR` and other relevant inputs and a code that is self-contained and runs using them and make sure the output with it is as expected. Also, in the edited code `samples` is undefined. Basically, we are looking for a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to demonstrate what you want to achieve. More info here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you have a c++ compiler installed on your machine? Would you be comfortable using a mex function written in c++ that can be called from Matlab? Or are you looking for an answer written entirely in MATLAB?

Comment: I understand. Hopefully the new block is what is needed. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence?lq=1 might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) & [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
append_col = zeros(size(abovethreshold,1),1);
df = diff([append_col abovethreshold append_col],[],2).'; %//'
[R1,C1] = find(df==1);
[R2,C2] = find(df==-1);
out = zeros(samples,1);
out(1:max(C1)) = accumarray(C1,R2 - R1,[],@max);
```

In the code posted above, we are creating a fat array with `abovethreshold` and then transposing it. From performance point of view, the transpose operation might not be the best thing to do. So, rather we can move things around it rather than itself, like so -

```
append_col = zeros(size(abovethreshold,1),1);
df = diff([append_col abovethreshold append_col],[],2); %//'
[R1,C1] = find(df==1);
[R2,C2] = find(df==-1);
[~,idx1] = sort(R1);
[~,idx2] = sort(R2);
out = zeros(samples,1);
out(1:max(R1)) = accumarray(R1(idx1),C2(idx2) - C1(idx1),[],@max);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about memory allocation, speed, etc... on huge arrays, I'd just do your same basic algorithm in c++. Throw this in something like  myfunction.cpp file and compile with `mex -largeArrayDims myfunction.cpp`.

You can then call from matlab with `counts = myfunction(allGSR, .05)`;

I haven't tested this beyond that it compiles.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
  if(nrhs != 2)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid number of inputs.  Shoudl be 2 input argument.");
  if(nlhs != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid number of outputs.  Should be 1 output arguments.");
  if(!mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[1]))
    mexErrMsgTxt("First two arguments are not doubles");

  const mxArray *input_array = prhs[0];
  const mxArray *threshold_array = prhs[1];
  size_t input_rows = mxGetM(input_array);
  size_t input_cols = mxGetN(input_array);
  size_t threshold_rows = mxGetM(threshold_array);
  size_t threshold_cols = mxGetN(threshold_array);
  if(threshold_rows != 1 || threshold_cols != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("threshold array should be a scalar");

  mxArray *output_array = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, input_rows, mxREAL);  
  double *output_data = mxGetPr(output_array);
  double *input_data  = mxGetPr(input_array);
  double threshold = *mxGetPr(threshold_array);


  for(int z = 0; z < input_rows; z++) {
    int count = 0;
    int max_count = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < input_cols; a++) {
      if(input_data[z + a * input_rows] < threshold) {
        count++;
      } else {
        if(count > max_count)
           max_count = count;
        count = 0;
      }
    }
    if(count > max_count)
      max_count = count;
    output_data[z] = max_count;
  }

  plhs[0] = output_array;
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to check for above or below threshold? Whatever you do, you'd change the `input_data[z + a * input_rows] < threshold)` to whatever comparison operator you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner, albeit slow since `cellfun` is a loop:

```
maxSIG=cellfun(@(x) max(getfield(regionprops(x),'Area')),mat2cell(allGSR,ones(6000,1),100));
```

The Image Processing Toolbox function `regionprops` identifies connected groups of 1's in a logical matrix. By operating on each row of your matrix, and returning specifically the `Area` property, we get the length of each connected segment of 1's in each row. The `max` function picks out the length in each row you're looking for.

Note the `mat2cell` call is necessary to split `allGSR` into a cell matrix of rows, so that `cellfun` can be called.