# Count time intervals for events greater than threshold

Tags: matlab, intervals, threshold

I am stuck at something in MATLAB and would appreciate if someone can help. Here is what I would like to do. I have a velocity field data w.r.t. time (see figure attached).

1. I would like to count number of time intervals (T1,T2,T3,etc) for which value of velocity is greater than threshold. Please note that I would like to count time intervals and not number of velocity points above threshold.
2. After doing step 1, I would like to somehow calculate average of time duration (e.g. average of T1, T2, T3, etc).
3. Finally, I want to calculate average value of velocity data for intervals T1, T2, T3, etc.

I think step 2 and 3 should be straightforward if I can get step 1 done. I would really appreciate any help. I am doing this in MATLAB but I am open to use any other tools if required. [image]

Comment: 2)"the average of time" means the average lengths of each interval? 3) Separately for each interval or one average value for all three intervals together?

Comment: So you'd like to [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) data that meets a certain criteria?

Comment: Related to above, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) and think about how you could adapt it to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the use of `bwconncomp`:

```
A = rand(1,100); %your 1d list of speeds
T = 0.5;

B = A > T;

tmp = bwconncomp(B); 

pxlist = tmp.PixelIdxList; %connected components are above thresh

N = zeros(1,length(pxlist));
V = zeros(1,length(pxlist));

for li = 1:length(pxlist)
    N(li) = length(pxlist{li});
    V(li) = mean(A(pxlist{li})); %avg velocity in interval li
end

avg = mean(N); %this is the avg. "time", i.e. length of connected components
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not have an image for this signal. Above image I just created to help understand the problem. I have an array in matlab for Velocity fluctuations. Is there any way to handle that?

Comment: Did you look at my code? `A` is your 1d array, or as you will an 1xN image. bwconncomp works just fine with that.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't see the code you posted. I will try that. However, can you please tell what is T? I need to have threshold of velocity signal and not the time (the dark solid line passing through the signal in the picture is some value of velocity , say V = 5 m/s).

Comment: T is the threshold ;)