# Zero in vector moving preceding value into new column

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
A = [1 7 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 5 3 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 4 3 10 3 5 3 2 1]
```

I would like the vector to look like this:

```
1 7 3 4

1 4 5 3 2 4

2 4 3 10 3 5 3 2 1
```

I am trying to delete the zeroes out of the vector and, when there is a zero, replace the preceding number after into a new column and continue through the length of the vector. I am currently using the command `L = A(A~=0)` to delete the zeroes, but get stuck there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that "when there is a zero to replace the preceding number after into a new column and continue through the length of the vector". `L = A(A~=0)` you should produce the expected result.

Comment: I suggest reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) and adapting it for your needs

Comment: Sorry the formatting got messed up on the submissions I would like the Vector to look like the correction

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want the output to be a cell ?

Comment: @Ratbert It would have to be, right?

Comment: My Broca's area also segfaults while parsing "replace the preceding number after into a new column and continue through the length of the vector"

Comment: @Beaker Well it could be a string too.

Comment: @Ratbert I guess that's a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be a matrix.. you can't. Matrices cannot have empty elements as you show. The best you can do is a cell array, where each element of the cell corresponds to a row in the "matrix".

First, we can find all the locations where there *isn't* a zero:

```
>> nonZeroIndices = find(A)

nonZeroIndices =
 1     2     3     4    11    12    13    14    15    16    24    25    26    27    28    29    30    31    32
```

It should be obvious that "runs" of indices corresponds to where there are non-zeroes in `A`. That is to say, the difference between some index `n` and `n-1` is 1. Let's use `diff` to find the delineations:

```
>> diff(nonZeroIndices)
ans = 1     1     1     7     1     1     1     1     1     8     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

The non-one values correspond to where those "breaks" in the runs occur. Let's find those indices..

```
>> breakIndices = find(diff(nonZeroIndices) > 1)
breakIndices =
 4    10
```

So `A(nonZeroIndices(1:4))`, `A(nonZeroIndices(5:10))`, and `A(nonZeroIndices(11:end))` correspond to the 3 "rows" we want. Note that each of these indices corresponds to the *end* of the run, so I'll prepend a 0 to it to make a `for` loop easier to work with.

Here is my final solution:

```
nonZeroIndices = find(A);
breakIndices = [0 find(diff(nonZeroIndices) > 1)];
for ii = 1:numel(breakIndices)
    if ii ~= numel(breakIndices)
        c{ii,:} = A(nonZeroIndices(breakIndices(ii)+1) : nonZeroIndices(breakIndices(ii+1)));
    else
        c{ii} = A(nonZeroIndices(breakIndices(ii)+1):end);
    end
    disp(c{ii})
end
```

Running this, you get the required output:

```
 1     7     3     4
 1     4     5     3     2     4
 2     4     3    10     3     5     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without loops:

```
A = [1 7 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 5 3 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 4 3 10 3 5 3 2 1]; %// data
nz = logical(A); %// logical index of nonzeros of A
ind = find(conv(2*([false nz])-1,[1 -1],'valid')==2); %// find ends of runs of zeros
B = zeros(size(A)); B(ind) = 1; B = cumsum(B); %// integer label for each group
result = accumarray(B(nz).', A(nz).', [], @(x){x.'}); %'// nonzero elements by group
```

The result is a cell array of row vectors. In your example,

```
>> celldisp(result)
 result{1} =
     1     7     3     4
result{2} =
     1     4     5     3     2     4
result{3} =
     2     4     3    10     3     5     3     2     1
```

Comment: @jez That would be nice! They tend to dislike language-specific tags, though :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output seems to not be a vector, but rather three separate vectors. I'm going to assume you want them as separate cells (`c{1}`, `c{2}` and `c{3}`) of a cell array `c`:

```
A = [1 7 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 5 3 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 4 3 10 3 5 3 2 1];
z = diff([0 A 0] == 0);
firstnonzero = find(z < 0);
lastnonzero  = find(z > 0) - 1;
c = {};
for i = 1:numel(firstnonzero)
   c{i} = A(firstnonzero(i):lastnonzero(i));
end
disp(c)
```