# Finding the distribution of length of islands in a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I will explain my question using an example. Imagine you have a 2D matrix like below:

```
5 4 3 8 0 0
5 4 2 9 1 0
5 6 2 7 2 0
5 4 7 9 0 0
5 6 7 1 2 0
```

By islands I mean column groups of same elements (except zeros).
I would like to find the histogram of length of `islands` except those consisting of zero elements.

[image]

This matrix has

```
island-length occurrence
  5               1
  2               3
  1               12
```

How can I realize this task using Matlab ?

Comment: This seems a very tough task, Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I tried using converting 2D array to 1D array and then following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence . But it has the disadvantage of being incapable of handling zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are shorter possibilities, but this will do - and it is fully vectorized:

```
A = [5 4 3 8 0 0
     5 4 2 9 1 0
     5 6 2 7 2 0
     5 4 7 9 0 0
     5 6 7 1 2 0]

%// pad zeros to first line of A
X(2:size(A,1)+1,:) = A;

%// differences of X
dX = diff(X)

%// cumulative sum of "logicalized" differences
cs = cumsum(logical(dX(:)))
%// filter out zeros
cs = cs(logical(A(:)))
%// count occurances
aa = accumarray(cs,1)

%// unique occurances
uaa = unique(aa)
%// count unique occurances
occ = hist(aa,uaa).'
%// accumarray may introduce new zeros, filter out
mask = logical(uaa)

%// output
out = [occ(mask) uaa(mask)]
```

---

```
out =

    12     1
     3     2
     1     5
```

Comment: @dexterdev I shortened and simplified the code, you should habe a look at my edit

Comment: Oh yes I looked at it. Simply great. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Needed a slight modification to one of my old snippets to filter the zeros. Here you go:

```
% Your Matrix
A = [ 5 4 3 8 0 0;
5 4 2 9 1 0;
5 6 2 7 2 0;
5 4 7 9 0 0;
5 6 7 1 2 0];

% Find Edges (Ends of Islands)
B = diff(A);
B = [ones(1,size(A,2));B~=0;ones(1,size(A,2))];

% At each column, find distances between island edges, filter out zero islands.
R = cell(size(A,2),1);
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    [C ~] = find(B(:,i));
    Ac = A(C(1:end-1),i);
    D = diff(C);
    D(Ac==0)=[];
    R{i} = D;
end

% Find histogram of island lengths
R = R(find(~cellfun(@isempty,R)),1);
R = cell2mat(R);
[a,~,c] = unique(R);
out = [a, accumarray(c,ones(size(R)))];
```