# Find series of the same value

Tags: matlab, series

Given a vector `A` that contains a sequence of numbers.

The objective is to find all series (longer than a given number "threshold") that contain the same value. The result should be the position of both first and last values of that series.

Example: given a vector `A` where:

```
A = [1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4];
```

and a threshold `B = 5;`

The results would be:

```
[9 13]  % a series contain only the number 1 with length equal to 5
[16 22] % a series contain only the number 2 with length equal to 7
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, do you have a specific question about your solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
 A=[1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4];
 B = 5;

[l c]= size(A);                   % to know the size of 'A'
K=1;                              % to define the length of the series 
W=1;                              % a value used to save the positions of the wanted series.

For i=1:c-1
      If A(i)==A(i+1)  
          K=k+1;
       Else 
              If  k>= B %  to test of the actual series is equal or longer than the given threshold
                  S(w,1)=i;  
                  S(w,2)= S(w,1)-k+1;  % saving the first position and the last position of the series in 'S'
                   w=w+1;
       end
        k=1;
end

S %                       the final result which is a table contain all wanted series.
```

the result is as follow:

```
S  13   9    % 13: the last position of the wanted series and 9 is the first position
   16  22
```

This one work soo good. But still... it is soo slow when its come to a big table.

Answer (score 1):

A faster, vectorized option is to modify the approach from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3274416/52738) for finding islands of zeroes:

```
A = [1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4];  % Sample data
B = 5;  % Threshold

tsig = (diff(A) ~= 0);
dsig = diff([1 tsig 1]);
startIndex = find(dsig < 0);
endIndex = find(dsig > 0)-1;
duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
stringIndex = (duration >= (B-1));
result = [startIndex(stringIndex); endIndex(stringIndex)+1].';
```

And the results:

```
result =

     9    13
    16    22
```