# How to get indices of a matrix of numbers?

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab matrix of numbers where every number is a measurement every 5 minutes.

How can I find the start and end indices of every block that is separated by more than 5 zeroes. It starts counting from the right, and continues the block till it finds greater than 5 zeroes. i.e.

```
   1 0 0 4 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 2 22 41 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 0 0 0 4
```

The blocks would be:

```
4 2 22 41 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 0 0 0 4
1 0 0 4 0 1 2
```

And I want to know their indices.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence

Answer (score 1):

If you have *Image Processing toolbox*, you can use [**`bwareaopen`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) for this purpose.

```
A = [1 0 0 4 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 2 22 41 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 0 0 0 4]; %Given array
tmp=~bwareaopen(~A, 6);   %Logical array of the blocks separated by greater than 5 zeros
tmp = diff([0, tmp, 0]);  %Padded with zeroes for the first & last indices respectively
startInd = find(tmp == 1);    %starting indices of the blocks
endInd = find(tmp == -1) - 1; %ending indices of the blocks
```

For the given array, it gives:

```
>> startInd

startInd =   %1st block starts from the 1st index, 2nd block starts from the 14th index
     1    14   

>> endInd

endInd =     %1st block ends at the 7th index, 2nd block ends at the 28th index 
     7    28
```