# Find regions of contiguous zeros in a binary array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have

```
x=[ 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

I want to find all the regions that have more than 5 zeros in a row. I want to find the index where it starts and where it stops.

In this case I want this: `c=[12 18]`. I can do it using for loops but I wonder if there is any better way, at least to find if there are some regions where this 'mask' ( `mask=[0 0 0 0 0]` ) appears.

Comment: what would the output be if multiple zero-regions existed in x?

Comment: Sounds like a classic convolution problem. Just use `conv`, pick out the maxima.

Comment: Do you want `c=[12 18]` or `c=[12 17]` because the last `0` in that sequence is at element `17`. so it the `18` intentional or a typo?

Comment: Though this isn't necessarily a duplicate, there are some similarities to the classic [island of zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274043/finding-islands-of-zeros-in-a-sequence) question.

Answer (score 2):

A convolution based approach:

```
n = 5;
x = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0];

end_idx = find(diff(conv(~x, ones(1,n))==n)==-1)
start_idx = find(diff(conv(~x, ones(1,n))==n)==1) - n + 2
```

returning

```
end_idx =

    6   14   25

start_idx =

    1    9   20
```

Note that this part is common to both lines: `diff(conv(~x, ones(1,n))==n)` so it would be more efficient to pull it out:

```
kernel = ones(1,n);
convolved = diff(conv(~x, kernel)==n);
end_idx = find(convolved==-1)
start_idx = find(convolved==1) - n + 2
```

Comment: Why isn't `2` an index where the mask fits? OP wants every occasion where 5 consecuetive zeros occur, and there's 6 on the start. So shouldn't `[2 6]` also be a fit?

Comment: @Adriaan I don't understand the OP to ask for that. *"I want to find all the regions that have more than 5 zeros in a row. I want to find the index where it starts and where it stops."* Sounds to me like eight `0`s in a row is just a single region requiring just the start and the stop. The one thing that might be wrong here is that I find regions that have five or more `0`s instead of strictly more than five but that's remedied by just changing `n` to be `6`.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that part, I thought he just wanted the mask. Yea, in that case your answer's the way to go for sure; I'm not even going to try to extend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp` this way:

- convert the array into a string
- remove the blanks
- use regexp to find the sequence of `0`

A possible implementation could be:

```
x=[ 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
% Convert the array to string and remove the blanks
str=strrep(num2str(x),' ','')

% Find the occurrences
[start_idx,end_idx]=regexp(str,'0{6,}')
```

This gives:

```
start_idx =  12
end_idx =  17
```

where `x(start_idx)` is the first element of the sequence and `x(end_idx)` is the last one

Applied to a more long sequence, `start_idx` and `end_idx` results being arrays:

```
x=[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]

start_idx =

    1    9   20

end_idx =

    6   14   25
```

Comment: Converting an array in a mode MATLAB's good at (numeric) to something slower (strings) doesn't sound like a particularly fast approach.