# Count length and frequency of island of consecutive numbers

Tags: matlab, binary, counting

I have a sequence of ones and zeros and I would like to count how often islands of consecutive ones appear.

Given:
`S = [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]`

By counting the islands of consecutive ones I mean this:
`R = [4 3 1]`
…because there are four single ones, three double ones and a single triplet of ones.

So that when multiplied by the length of the islands [1 2 3].

`[4 3 1] * [1 2 3]’ = 13`

Which corresponds to `sum(S)`, because there are thirteen ones.

I hope to vectorize the solution rather than loop something.

I came up with something like:
`R = histcounts(diff( [0 (find( ~ (S > 0) ) ) numel(S)+1] ))`

But the result does not make much sense. It counts too many triplets.
All pieces of code I find on the internet revolve around `diff([0 something numel(S)])` but the questions are always slightly different and don’t really help me

Thankful for any advice!

Comment: You can use any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3274043/2586922) and then `result = histcounts(duration, [1:max(duration)+1]);`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? Why use complicated code you don’t understand rather than a simpler code with a loop? Being able to maintain code is the most important part of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it.  Hopefully the comments are clear.

```
S = [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1];
% use diff to find the rising and falling edges, padding the start and end with 0
edges = diff([0,S,0]); 
% get a list of the rising edges
rising = find(edges==1);
% and falling edges
falling = find(edges==-1);
% and thereby get the lengths of all the runs
SRuns = falling - rising;
% The longest run
maxRun = max(SRuns);
% Finally make a histogram, putting the bin centres 
R = hist(SRuns,1:maxRun);
```

Comment: better late than never: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also obtain the same result with:

```
x = find(S==1)-(1:sum(S)) %give a specific value to each group of 1
h = histc(x,x)            %compute the length of each group, you can also use histc(x,unique(x))
r = histc(h,1:max(h))     %count the occurence of each length
```

Result:

```
r = 
 4,3,1
```