# Vectorizing the Notion of Colon (:) - values between two vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I have two vectors, `idx1` and `idx2`, and I want to obtain the values between them. If `idx1` and `idx2` were numbers and not vectors, I could do that the following way:

```
idx1=1;
idx2=5;
values=idx1:idx2 

% Result
 % values =
 % 
 %    1     2     3     4     5
```

But in my case, `idx1` and `idx2` are vectors of variable length. For example, for length=2:

```
idx1=[5,9];
idx2=[9 11];
```

Can I use the colon operator to directly obtain the values in between? This is, something similar to the following:

```
values = [5     6     7     8     9     9    10    11]
```

I know I can do `idx1(1):idx2(1)` and `idx1(2):idx2(2)`, this is, extract the values for each column separately, so if there is no other solution, I can do this with a for-loop, but maybe Matlab can do this more easily.

Comment: `values` is not possible in MATLAB. A 5-vector vertically concatentated by a 3-vector?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. I'm going to correct that. I don't mind if the values are all in the same row, I just need all the values between those indexes.

Comment: There is an excellent blog post on this topic by Loren at Mathworks: [Vectorizing the Notion of Colon (:)](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/10/13/vectorizing-the-notion-of-colon)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your sample output is not legal. A matrix cannot have rows of different length. What you can do is create a cell array using `arrayfun`:

```
values = arrayfun(@colon, idx1, idx2, 'Uniform', false)
```

To convert the resulting cell array into a vector, you can use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
values = cell2mat(values);
```

Alternatively, if all vectors in the resulting cell array have the same length, you can construct an output matrix as follows:

```
values = vertcat(values{:});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. As I just need the values and I do not mind from which row I've obtained them, I can use `horzcat` and `unique`, like this: `values = unique(horzcat(values{:}));` I'm going to read more about arrayfun, it seems to be very useful

Comment: @Digna It may look pretty, but don't abuse it. It is quite slow when compared to a `for` loop (even more so if a "vectorized" solution exists), so you should usually prefer the latter (unless speed is not an issue)... Also note that you can write `[blah blah]` instead of `horzcat(blah blah)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the union of the sets.  Given the values of `idx1` and `idx2` you supplied, run

```
values = union(idx1(1):idx1(2), idx2(1):idx2(2));
```

Which will yield a vector with the values `[5 6 7 8 9 10 11]`, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that `idx1` and `idx2` may have any length (it depends on the signal I am processing), and this solution would be difficult to apply in this case, wouldn't it? (Perhaps I'm missing something) :)

Comment: Ah, whoops. Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  Taking the Cartesian product using `arrayfun` seems to be the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get @Eitan's solution to work, apparently you need to specify parameters to colon. The small modification that follows got it working on my R2010b version:

```
step = 1; 
idx1 = [5, 9];
idx2 = [9, 11];
values = arrayfun(@(x,y)colon(x, step, y), idx1, idx2, 'UniformOutput', false);
values=vertcat(cell2mat(values));
```

Note that `step = 1` is actually the default value in `colon`, and `Uniform` can be used in place of `UniformOutput`, but I've included these for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great blog post by *Loren* called [Vectorizing the Notion of Colon (:)](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/10/13/vectorizing-the-notion-of-colon/). It includes an answer that is about 5 times faster (for large arrays) than using `arrayfun` or a `for`-loop and is similar to run-length-decoding:

> The idea is to expand the colon sequences out. I know the lengths of
>   each sequence so I know the starting points in the output array. Fill
>   the values after the start values with 1s. Then I figure out how much
>   to jump from the end of one sequence to the beginning of the next one.
>   If there are repeated start values, the jumps might be negative. Once
>   this array is filled, the output is simply the cumulative sum or
>   cumsum of the sequence.
>
> ```
> function x = coloncatrld(start, stop)
> % COLONCAT Concatenate colon expressions
> %    X = COLONCAT(START,STOP) returns a vector containing the values
> %    [START(1):STOP(1) START(2):STOP(2) START(END):STOP(END)].
>
> % Based on Peter Acklam's code for run length decoding.
> len = stop - start + 1;
>
> % keep only sequences whose length is positive
> pos = len > 0;
> start = start(pos);
> stop = stop(pos);
> len = len(pos);
> if isempty(len)
>     x = [];
>     return;
> end
>
> % expand out the colon expressions
> endlocs = cumsum(len);  
> incr = ones(1, endlocs(end));  
> jumps = start(2:end) - stop(1:end-1);  
> incr(endlocs(1:end-1)+1) = jumps;
> incr(1) = start(1);
> x = cumsum(incr);
> ```