# Array from vector on the basis of a second array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a vector `v`. I need to form an array `a` containing elements specified according to another array `b`. Each row in `a` (let's denote it by `r`) should contain all elements from `v`, with starting and ending indices corresponding to the first and last elements given in the matching column in `b`.  For instance:

```
A(1, :) = v(b(1, 1):b(2, 1));
A(2, :) = v(b(1, 2):b(2, 2));
A(3, :) = v(b(1, 3):b(2, 3));
```

and so on. Obviously `b(2,:) = b(1,:) + constant`.

Can I do this without a loop in MATLAB?

Comment: I can only think of using a loop.

Comment: If you can add your coding to the question, that would help in answering.

Comment: related question (and possibly a duplicate): [Matlab's colon operator: values between two vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341798/matlabs-colon-operator-values-between-two-vectors)

Comment: @user2000581 Have you tried my alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
N=8; P=3; M=5;
v = rand(N,1);
b = zeros(2,M);
b(1,:) = [1 2 4 5 6];
b(2,:) = b(1,:) + P - 1;
A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i0,i1) v(i0:i1),b(1,:),b(2,:),'UniformOutput',false))'
```

Comment: However, just to point out, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why), although loops take more space, they are faster.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you need to do this without loops?

Comment: @user2000581 Mind you that `bsxfun` is usually faster than both :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear indexing and `bsxfun` to directly access the elements:

```
A = v(bsxfun(@plus, b(1,:).', 0:b(2,1)-b(1,1)));
```