# Create array from two arrays elements in pairs without loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, vectorization

Simple question here. I have arrays:

```
a = [ 600 746 8556 90456 ]
b = [ 684 864 8600 90500 ]
```

and I want to get:

```
output = [ a(1):b(1) a(2):b(2) a(3):b(3) a(4):b(4) ]
```

(or either `[ a(1):b(1); a(2):b(2); a(3):b(3); a(4):b(4) ]`, I don't care)

I cannot realize how to do this without using a loop, but I know it should be a way.

Any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen this one. Let's go on duplicate hunt!
Here are plenty of methods by *Loren*: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/10/13/vectorizing-the-notion-of-colon/

Comment: @knedlsepp Indeed, I believe I have seen similar questions before, but they are not very googleable.

Comment: I will look for the one with the broadest answers and rename it to: "Vectorizing the notion of colon (:)".

Comment: @knedlsepp Actually having appropriate titles help a lot in googling, so that's a good idea!

Comment: @Divakar: I propose [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341798/matlabs-colon-operator-values-between-two-vectors). It has the most views and already four linked ones. Feel free to add your `bsxfun`-solution there.

Comment: Accepted answer on that question is virtually identical to my answer, except for using `colon`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: Isn't that a great way of approval to have found a neat solution. ;-) In terms of speed it might be outperformed by loops though.

Comment: @knedlsepp I think I will just leave it here, at least for now. Good find that one!!

Comment: Sorry for duplicating.
I knew there were many chances it already existed but yes, it wasn't very googleable. cheers

Comment: @myradio It prompted new approaches though! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Approach #1**

`Vectorized` approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability -

```
%// Get "extents" formed with each pair of "a" and "b" and max extent
ext = b-a
max_ext = max(ext)

%// Extend all a's to max possible extent
allvals = bsxfun(@plus,a,[0:max_ext]')  %//'

%// Get mask of valid extensions and use it to have the final output
mask  = bsxfun(@le,[0:max_ext]',ext)  %//'
out  = allvals(mask).'
```

---

**Approach #2**

Listing here is a [`cumsum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) based approach that has to be more memory efficient and faster than both the earlier listed `bsxfun` based approach and [`arrayfun` based approach in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28973261/3293881). Here's the code -

```
%// Get "extents" formed with each pair of "a" and "b"
ext = b-a;

%// Ignore cases when "a" might be greater than "b"
a = a(ext>=0);
b = b(ext>=0);
ext = b-a;

if numel(ext)>1

    %// Strategically place "differentiated" values from array,a
    idx = ones(sum(ext+1),1);
    idx([1 cumsum(ext(1:end-1)+1)+1]) = [a(1) diff(a)-ext(1:end-1)];

    %// Perform cumulative summation to have the final output
    out = cumsum(idx)

else %// Leftover cases when there are one or no valid boundaries:(a->b)
    out = a:b
end
```

---

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
     6    12    43
>> b
b =
     8    17    43
>> out
out =
     6     7     8    12    13    14    15    16    17    43
```

Comment: Well done avoiding very large numbers by using `b-a`

Comment: @LuisMendo I think that's the only way here. But, still in `allvals` I am `extending`, a lot of whom are descarded in the next step with the masking.

Comment: Want to give another +1 for the second approach. In case a might be larger than b `a=a(ext>=0);b=b(ext>=0);` should be inserted as a second line.

Comment: Great take on the `cumsum` version. To be equivalent to the `bsxfun` solution we need to strip away zero or negative runs though, as in: `a=[1,10]`, `b=[0,11]`. - Edit: Ok, Daniel already got the solution.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, edited with it, good suggestion on that!!

Comment: As I'm currently comparing all the approaches, I have come across yet another corner case: If after `ext = b(ext>=0)-a;` it is empty, the first `cumsum` line fails. (Loren also has to check this explicitly in her `cumsum` approach)

Comment: @knedlsepp That is when all `a` elements are greater than `b`, right?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, but I just saw it even fails for all but one: `a = [9    10    16    19]; b = [7     9    15    23];`

Comment: @knedlsepp Yup! good catch that one! Edited to work with those corner cases.

Comment: Great! If you are interested in terms of speed: Loren's answer is the tiniest bit faster than yours, then comes a factor of five to the `for` loop and yet another factor of `five` for the current `arrayfun` solution, (which becomes nearly as fast as the `for` loop if `@(start, stop) start:stop` is swapped for `@colon`).

Comment: @knedlsepp Is the fastest one `Run-Length Decoding` based? That looks very close to the Approach #2 of this one, or I might have a complicated it a tiny bit here, but looks close.

Comment: Yup. It's the `cumsum` one I mentioned earlier. I have given it some thought to directly use a `runLengthDecode` function, but I guess it is more similar to a RLE code than actually using one.

Answer (score 7):

One-liner using [arrayfun](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), [cell2mat](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and an [anonymous function](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
output = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(start, stop) start:stop, a, b, 'uni', 0))
```

Explanation: the function `arrayfun` iterates in parallel over the vectors `a` and `b`, and then calls the anonymous function for every pair of their elements. The anonymous function returns a vector of varying size instead of a scalar, so you need to use `'UniformOutput', false` (which can be abbreviated to `'uni', 0`) to make `arrayfun` return a cell array. Finally, you use `cell2mat` to squeeze the cell array together into a vector.

Quick test:

```
>> a = [10, 20, 40];
>> b = [13, 22, 45];
>> output = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(start, stop) start:stop, a, b, 'uni', 0))
output =
    10    11    12    13    20    21    22    40    41    42    43    44    45
```

Comment: In case you're interested: As I'm currently testing all the solutions: I get a 5x speedup if I use `@colon` instead of `@(start, stop) start:stop`. Which makes this pretty much as fast as the `for` loop. The `cumsum` approach is about 5 times faster for large arrays. (Which isn't really that much, considering `arrayfun`'s bad reputation.)

Comment: @knedlsepp I didn't know `@colon` even existed!

Comment: @LuisMendo: As this is basically the only use-case, I think you will still be able to live without it. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Nope. Now that I know of it existence, I'll try to find a way to include it in a near-future answer :-)