# Matlab: Sum corresponding values if index is within a range

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have been going crazy trying to figure a way to speed this up.  Right now my current code talks ~200 sec looping over 77000 events.  I was hoping someone might be able to help me speed this up because I have to do about 500 of these.

Problem: 
I have arrays (both 200000x1) that correspond to Energy and Position of a hit over 77000 events.  I have the range of each event separated into two arrays, event_start and event_end.  First thing I do is look for the position in a specific range, then I put the correspond energy in its own array.  To get what I need out of this information, I loop through each event and its corresponding start/end to sum up all the energies from each it hit.  My code is below:

```
    indx_pos = find(pos>0.7 & pos<2.0);
    energy = HitEnergy(indx_pos);

    for i=1:n_events
        Etotal(i) = sum(energy(find(indx_pos>=event_start(i) …
        & indx_pos<=event_end(i))));    
    end
```

Sample input & output:

```
% Sample input 
% pos and energy same length

n_events = 3;
event_start = [1 3 7]';
event_end   = [2 6 8]';

pos = [0.75 0.8 2.1 3.6 1.9 0.5 21.0 3.1]';
HitEnergy = [0.002 0.004 0.01 0.0005 0.08  0.1 1.7 0.007]';


%  Sample Output
Etotal = 0.0060
         0.0800
              0
```

Comment: Post a small example with input and desired output

Comment: Are the start/end ranges overlapping? If not, it's easy to do this with `accumarray`. Also, you don't need the call to `find` inside your loop.

Comment: The start/end ranges are not overlapping.  I've never used accumarray but I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1: Generic case**

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and `matrix-multiplication` -

```
mask = bsxfun(@ge,indx_pos,event_start.') & bsxfun(@le,indx_pos,event_end.')
Etotal = energy.'*mask
```

This could be a bit `memory-hungry` if `indx_pos` has lots of elements in it.

---

**Approach #2: Non-overlapping start/end ranges case**

One can use [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for this special case like so -

```
%// Setup ID array for use in accumarray later on
loc(numel(pos))=0; %// Fast pre-allocation scheme
valids = event_end+1<=numel(pos);
loc(event_end(valids)+1) = -1*(1:sum(valids));
loc(event_start) = loc(event_start)+(1:numel(event_end));
id = cumsum(loc);

%// Set elements as zeros in HitEnergy that do not satisfy the criteria:
%// pos>0.7 & pos<2.0
HitEnergy_select = (pos>0.7 & pos<2.0).*HitEnergy(:);

%// Discard elments in HitEnergy_select & id that have IDs as zeros  
HitEnergy_select = HitEnergy_select(id~=0);
id = id(id~=0);

%// Accumulate summations as done inside the loop in the original code 
Etotal = accumarray(id(:),HitEnergy_select);
```

Comment: @ABD_worley Check out newly added approach too!

Comment: Clearly there was a possibility to simplify `accumarray` for the non-overlapping case. I just couldn't think of it!

Comment: @ABD_worley So, did you get any speedup with the second approach? Kinda curious about it!

Comment: Hm. Interestingly I don't see that much of a difference, even though I thought my approach is more computationally intensive.

Comment: @Divakar The second approach was crazy fast!  1.5 sec compared to my 200 sec.  Thanks.

Comment: @ABD_worley Wow, that's massive! Appreciate the update!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for every event you are searching the entire vector `indx_pos`.
Constrain your search inside the loop to only the range from `event_start(i)` to `event_end(i)`:

```
for i = 1:n_events
    I = event_start(i):event_end(i);
    posIIsWithinRange = pos(I)>0.7 & pos(I)<2.0;
    Etotal(i) = sum(HitEnergy(I(posIIsWithinRange)));
end
```

You could also use a vectorized version based on [run length decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28501418/3139711) and [vectorizing the notion of colon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28975751/3139711). (Download the functions `coloncatrld` and `runLengthDecode`.)

```
I = coloncatrld(event_start, event_end);
energy = HitEnergy(I);
eventNum = runLengthDecode(event_end - event_start+1);
posIIsWithinRange = pos(I)>0.7 & pos(I)<2.0;
Etotal = accumarray(eventNum(posIIsWithinRange), energy(posIIsWithinRange), [n_events,1]);
```

This is similar to *Divakar*'s Approach #2 with the addition that it should work for overlapping ranges too.

Comment: These two method you presented were about 2 sec too compared to my 200 sec.  You guys are awesome.  Thank you so much!