# Matlab sum function from index to index

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a better way to calculate the sum off all elements from index X to index Y, if I have a list of indexes.
For example:

```
a = {1, 40, 77} % indexes
cell_elements = {1,1,1.....,1} %100 elements, each 1
```

My current idea looks something like this:

```
        counter = 1;
        for k=1:length(cell_elements)
            if(%Some condition) %condition is true for k=1,40 and 77
                sum = sum+cell_elements(k);
                result(counter) = sum;
                sum=0;
                counter = counter+1;      
            else
                sum = sum+cell_elements(k);
            end
        end
```

I would like to improve the code, since I have the feeling that the problematic is simple, but due to my lack of experience in matlab my code is too long.

Is there any function, where I could just pass a list of indexes and it will do the same job as the code above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: Sum corresponding values if index is within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393234/matlab-sum-corresponding-values-if-index-is-within-a-range)

Comment: What is the expected result with the given example ? Why are you using cell instead or array ? What is `pkt_size` ? BTW you shadow the built-in function `sum` if you use `sum` as a variable name which is not recommanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `array` instead of `cell`
- Also since your `cell_elements` are all `1s`, you can use the matrix
  `ones(row, column)`

Specify the `row` and the `column`, here `row is 1` and column is `100` this is the code

```
cell_elements = ones(1, 100)
```

- Define `a` as an array `a = [1, 40, 77]`
- First 40 elements are elements having indices from `1 to 40`, in Matlab
  this is equivalent to `1:40`, in order to include the array `a`, 
  since `a(1) = 1 and a(2) = 40`; set `1:40` as `a(1):a(2)` 
  First 40 elements will be

```
First_40_elements = cell_elements(a(1):a(2));
```

To sum them all together use Matlab built in function `sum` as follow

```
Sum_First_40_elements = sum(First_40_elements)
```

- For the second 37 elements the indices start from `41 to 77`, in Matlab
  written as `41:77`, using array `a`, `a(2)+1:a(3)`
  Following the logic above

```
Second_37_elements = cell_elements(a(2)+1:a(3));

Sum_Second_37_elements = cell_elements(Second_37_elements);
```

## The entire code is as follow

```
cell_elements = ones(1,100);

a = [1,40,77];

First_40_elements =  cell_elements(a(1):a(2));

Sum_First_40_elements = sum(First_40_elements);
% 40

Second_37_elements =  cell_elements(a(2)+1:a(3));

Sum_Second_37_elements = sum(Second_37_elements);
% 37
```

## The dynamic way is as follow

```
cell_elements = ones(1,100);
a = [1,25,40, 67, 80, 95];

element_sum = zeros(1, length(a)-1);
for i = 1:length(a)-1
    if i == 1
        element_sum(i) =  sum(cell_elements(a(i):a(i+1)));
    else
        element_sum(i) =  sum(cell_elements(a(i)+1:a(i+1)));
    end
end
```

## Result

```
>> element_sum

element_sum =

    25    15    27    13    15

>>
```

Comment: yes, but I am looking for all values between X and Y, and not the corresponding values at index X and Y. So, I am looking for a neat way to sum everything between X,Y, or if I follow the example you have given:
a=[1,40,70]
result = [1+1+1+1...+1, 1+1+1..+1] %first element a sum of 40, second of 30, in case all elements are ones

Comment: @CroatiaHR, "_from index X to index Y_" ... why do you have 3 indices then ? Do you mean the sum from index 1 to index 40, then the sum from index 40 to index 77 ?

Comment: Well, this is quite close to what I am looking for. But I believe it is not dynamically when it comes to the size of a. In this way, you have a specific size of 3, but in my program, I want to make it flexible in case it has to read in the size. I will still mark it as an answer, since you did answer on the given example, but I will be happy if you could give me an replay if there is a dynamic approach to it

Comment: @CroatiaHR check below, I added a dynamic way using a `for loop`