# Extract fixed amounts of data from array based on a list of indices

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have the array

```
a=1:20
```

and a series of indices which indicate where I want to start pulling data out:

```
i=[4,12]
```

For each index `i`, I want that index and the next four (well, `x`, really) elements in a column or row. I'll avoid getting to close to the end of the array, so that special case can be disregarded.

If I was hard-coding this, I could use:

```
a([4:8;12:16])
```

and this would achieve my result.

But `i` may have many different values.

Any thoughts on how I can transform a list of indices into a matrix of ranges, or other ways to solve this problem?

**EDIT**
I am using Matlab 2007; it would be preferable if the solution relied solely on Matlab's internals and toolboxes. `bsxfun` is not present until 2007a.

Comment: What if the ranges overlap? Would you like to get the same element twice, or just once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vectorized array creation from a list of start/end indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807270/vectorized-array-creation-from-a-list-of-start-end-indices)

Comment: @Jonas, the ranges should be considered independent. If they overlap they return the same data as if they did not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `i` be your indicesx and `x` the number of elements you want in addition to the elements in `i`, then you can use

```
i = [4 6 8];
x = 4; 

bsxfun(@plus, 0:x, i(:))
```

to get a matrix of indices:

```
ans =

     4     5     6     7     8
     6     7     8     9    10
     8     9    10    11    12
```

If you do not have access to `bsxfun` you can use `repmat` instead:

```
i = [4 6 8];
x = 4; 

repmat(i(:), 1, x+1) + repmat(0:x, length(i), 1)
```

Comment: My apologies, my version of Matlab (2007) doesn't seem to have `bsxfun`.

Comment: I guess my reply was too late

Comment: Wow, that `repmat` solution is sneaky! Thanks, @H.Muster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without bsxfun but with repmat inspired by the previous answer.

```
i = [4 6 8];
x = 4;
p = repmat(1:x,length(i),1);
q = repmat(i',1,x);
p+q
```

Comment: But not too late for an upvote! :-) To be fair, we must say that H.Muster's answer also has a secondary method which would be preferable if I wasn't using "Matlab from the Stone Age".