# Convert numbers to sequence of numbers in cell-array rows

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to convert `[5,3,7]` to a cell array where every row would be a range from '`1:to_the_respective_number`'. However this seems surprisingly hard to achieve. 
Can someone point out where I went wrong?

```
nums=[5,3,7];
cellfun(@(x) 1:x, num2cell(nums),'UniformOutput',0)

ans =
  1×3 cell array
    {1×5 double}    {1×3 double}    {1×7 double}
```

what I actually wanted to get is (stiched this together in the variable explorer)

```
{1,2,3,4,5,[],[];1,2,3,[],[],[],[];1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
ans =
  3×7 cell array
    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}    {[       4]}    {[       5]}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}    {[       4]}    {[       5]}    {[       6]}    {[       7]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to get the desired result:

1.Using `arrayfun`.

```
nums=[5,3,7];
m = max(nums);
row  = arrayfun(@(x){[num2cell(1:x) cell(1, m-x)]}, nums );
result = vertcat(row{:});
```

2.A vectorized solution.

```
nums=[5,3,7];
m = max(nums);  
result = repmat(num2cell(1:m),numel(nums),1);
result(bsxfun(@gt, 1:m , nums.'))={[]};
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to opperate on an array so there's no need to convert to a cell array first. Just use `arrayfun(___, 'UniformOutput', false`).

```
>> nums = [5,3,7];
>> res = arrayfun(@(x) 1:x, nums, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The result is

```
>> res{:}
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5
ans =
     1     2     3
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)...

> B = arrayfun(___,Name,Value) applies func with additional options specified by one or more Name,Value pair arguments. **For example, to return output values in a cell array, specify 'UniformOutput',false**. You can return B as a cell array when func returns values that cannot be concatenated into an array. You can use Name,Value pair arguments with the input arguments of either of the previous syntaxes.

Answer (score 3):

If a 3-by-7 numeric matrix with zeroes as place holders is sufficient, you could adapt the [1-D solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2807994/52738) into a 2-D solution as follows:

```
nums = [5 3 7];
N = numel(nums);
maxNum = max(nums);
index = nums.*N+(1:3);

res = [ones(N, 1) zeros(N, maxNum)];
res(index) = -1;
res = cumsum(res, 2);
res(index) = -nums;
res = cumsum(res(:, 1:maxNum), 2);
```

And the resulting matrix:

```
res =

     1     2     3     4     5     0     0
     1     2     3     0     0     0     0
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
```